# How do I get the current date in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, date-formatting

How do I get the current date in JavaScript?

Comment: `var currentTime = new Date();`

Comment: See the [documentation for the Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date). It has examples.

Comment: this would help you http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptdate.php

Comment: `new Date()` returns the current *time*, not the current *date*. The distinction matters if you're trying to compare it against another date which doesn't have a time component (ie, is at midnight).

Comment: use momentJs, this lib is gold for developers.

Comment: @SteveBennett Actually, it returns the current date _and_ time. JavaScript doesn't have separate objects to represent a date-only value or a time-only value. It has only `Date`, which incorporates both. So, even if the question isn't exactly clear, the expected answer is to obtain the current system date and time, which is exactly what `new Date()` returns, so +1 to @Hendrik for the most concise answer.

Comment: See this post : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30245911/1579667

Comment: Surprised to not see a comment about the great date-fns library.  Modular (just import what you need), treats Dates as immutable, work with native Date objects, faster than Moment.

Comment: **Your question is very broad!** Do you want a string (easy) or a date object (traps)? Do you want the current date where you are, or in London, or somewhere else? ***[BEWARE THE TIMEZONE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38050824/1585345)***

Comment: new Date() is still valid and best answer but after that the need of particular format comes up and I would suggest to use toLocaleDateString with new Date e.g. ```new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {year: "numeric", month: "2-digit", day: "2-digit"})```which in the end give you formatted current date in this format  08/06/2021.

Comment: [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) is a modern library from one of the momentjs developers. Really nice interface and APIs!

Answer (score 3431, accepted):

Use `new Date()` to generate a new `Date` object containing the current date and time.

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
document.write(today);
```

This will give you today's date in the format of mm/dd/yyyy.

Simply change `today = mm +'/'+ dd +'/'+ yyyy;` to whatever format you wish.

Comment: thanks for the code.. but what I still don't get it, is the line if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} ... why < 10? from what I understand from the code is if day's character is less than 2, just add a preceding 0 in front of the day.. but why 10?

Comment: @imin: because less than 2 characters means 1 character... and everything under 10 (1 to 9) is 1 character, so we'll have `01`, `02`, ..., `09`

Comment: @MounaCheikhna - How could we be in the year 999?

Comment: Swap around the month and date if you're not in north America.

Comment: @MounaCheikhna why are you adding 1900? If we were in the year 999, this would make it 2899 (999 + 1900)

Comment: I wrapped it in a function for my own use, providing it here > http://jsfiddle.net/johndkane/cmzppwps/

Comment: The new `Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()` method is a more flexible solution. It's a part of JavaScript since ECMAScript 5.1 and is well-supported  by evergreen browsers. [MDN: `toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Comment: Today I found a pretty neat trick.  `('0' + today.getDate()).slice(-2)` This returns the current date always as 2 digits.

Comment: Oh man, twelve lines of code just to get the current date. In Delphi it would be just "formatdatetime('mm/dd/yyyy',now)" . Miss the old times :)

Comment: date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB')

Comment: after the edit from March 2019, this answer is using ES2017 features (`padStart`)  that will NOT work in Internet Explorer (any version)

Comment: @Aprillion just use polyfills such as corejs

Comment: Why can't we just use the simple getDate(), getMonth() methods. What is reason we are putting padStart and + 1 with that. I tried this and it is working fine. `var today = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = day =today.getDate();
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = month=today.getMonth();
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = year=today.getFullYear();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = year.toString()+month.toString()+day.toString();`

Answer (score 537):

```js
var utc = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,'/');
document.write(utc);
```

Use the `replace` option if you're going to reuse the `utc` variable, such as `new Date(utc)`, as Firefox and Safari don't recognize a date with dashes.

Comment: I dont think so :) Seems pretty straightforward!

Comment: toJSON() returns as utc datetime

Comment: It returns a JSON datetime. `toUTCString()` returns as utc datetime.

Comment: It doesn't consider TimezoneOffset.  At my time of testing, I was seeking "now" and I got "yesterday". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646446/javascript-date-tojson-produces-a-date-which-has-wrong-hours-and-minutes

Comment: Perfect. This is the cleanest way to do this I'm seeing here. Works well in MomentJS for "Today, Not Now" `moment( new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10) )`

Comment: In that case you can use `moment().startOf("day")`

Comment: I posted a slightly modified answer that takes TimezoneOffset into account: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31934378/1338062

Comment: Works but I had enclose `(new Date()).toJSON().slice(0,10)`

Comment: `.toJSON()` includes time zone information; `.slice()` strips it.

Comment: .toJSON() gives the current datetime in UTC. Since the question was with respect to current date alone, slice answers it.

Comment: You'll need to replace dashes with slashes by adding `.replace(/-/g,'/')`, so it becomes `new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,'/')` as FireFox and Safari don't recognize a date with dashes such as "2016-12-27".

Comment: This will start failing in the year 10000.

Comment: This does not answer ISO. So it's not a full answer..

Answer (score 463):

**The shortest possible.**

To get format like "2018-08-03":

```js
let today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)

console.log(today)
```

To get format like "8/3/2018":

```js
let today = new Date().toLocaleDateString()

console.log(today)
```

Also, you can pass [locale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#Using_locales) as argument, for example `toLocaleDateString("sr")`, etc.

Comment: This still fails due to time zone shift.

Comment: Your second answer is the best.

Comment: Note that this returns the day at UTC+0, but not the local day.

Answer (score 280):

> ***UPDATED!***, Scroll Down

If you want something simple pretty to the end-user ... *`Also, fixed a small suffix issue in the first version below. Now properly returns suffix.`*

```js
var objToday = new Date(),
 weekday = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'),
 dayOfWeek = weekday[objToday.getDay()],
 domEnder = function() { var a = objToday; if (/1/.test(parseInt((a + "").charAt(0)))) return "th"; a = parseInt((a + "").charAt(1)); return 1 == a ? "st" : 2 == a ? "nd" : 3 == a ? "rd" : "th" }(),
 dayOfMonth = today + ( objToday.getDate() < 10) ? '0' + objToday.getDate() + domEnder : objToday.getDate() + domEnder,
 months = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'),
 curMonth = months[objToday.getMonth()],
 curYear = objToday.getFullYear(),
 curHour = objToday.getHours() > 12 ? objToday.getHours() - 12 : (objToday.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + objToday.getHours() : objToday.getHours()),
 curMinute = objToday.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + objToday.getMinutes() : objToday.getMinutes(),
 curSeconds = objToday.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + objToday.getSeconds() : objToday.getSeconds(),
 curMeridiem = objToday.getHours() > 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
var today = curHour + ":" + curMinute + "." + curSeconds + curMeridiem + " " + dayOfWeek + " " + dayOfMonth + " of " + curMonth + ", " + curYear;

document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].textContent = today;
```

```html
<h1></h1>
```

> **UBBER UPDATE** After much procrastination, I've finally [**GitHubbed**](https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/JavaScriptDateFormat) and updated this with the final solution I've been using for myself. It's even had some last-minute edits to make it sweeter! If you're looking for the old [jsFiddle, please see this](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/rYzAY/).

This update comes in <s>2</s> flavors, still relatively small, though not as small as my above, original answer. If you want extremely small, go with that. 
 Also Note: This is still less bloated than moment.js. While moment.js is nice, imo, it has too many secular methods, which require learning moment as if it were a language. Mine here uses the same common format as [PHP: date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

#### Quick Links

- [Date.format.min.js](https://cdn.rawgit.com/JDMcKinstry/JavaScriptDateFormat/master/Date.format.min.js) 5.08 KB
- [dateFormat.min.js](https://cdn.rawgit.com/JDMcKinstry/JavaScriptDateFormat/master/dateFormat.min.js) 4.16 KB

> **Flavor 1 [`new Date().format(String)`](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/smdz6d43/)**
>   My Personal Fav. I know the taboo but works great on the Date Object. Just be aware of any other mods you may have to the Date Object.

```
//  use as simple as
new Date().format('m-d-Y h:i:s');   //  07-06-2016 06:38:34
```

> **Flavor 2 [`dateFormat(Date, String)`](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/tcqpw5d7/)**
>   More traditional all-in-one method. Has all the ability of the previous, but is called via the method with Date param.

```
//  use as simple as
dateFormat(new Date(), 'm-d-Y h:i:s');  //  07-06-2016 06:38:34
```

> **BONUS Flavor (requires jQuery) [`$.date(Date, String)`](https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/jQuery-Date)**
>   This contains much more than just a simple `format` option. It extends the base Date object and includes methods such as `addDays`. For more information, please see the [*Git*](https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/jQuery-Date).

In this mod, the format characters are inspired by [PHP: date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). For a complete list, please see my [README](https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/JavaScriptDateFormat/blob/master/README.md)

This mod also has a much longer list of pre-made formats. To use a premade format, simply enter its key name. `dateFormat(new Date(), 'pretty-a');`

- 'compound'

  - 'commonLogFormat' == 'd/M/Y:G:i:s'
  - 'exif' == 'Y:m:d G:i:s'
  - 'isoYearWeek' == 'Y\\WW'
  - 'isoYearWeek2' == 'Y-\\WW'
  - 'isoYearWeekDay' == 'Y\\WWj'
  - 'isoYearWeekDay2' == 'Y-\\WW-j'
  - 'mySQL' == 'Y-m-d h:i:s'
  - 'postgreSQL' == 'Y.z'
  - 'postgreSQL2' == 'Yz'
  - 'soap' == 'Y-m-d\\TH:i:s.u'
  - 'soap2' == 'Y-m-d\\TH:i:s.uP'
  - 'unixTimestamp' == '@U'
  - 'xmlrpc' == 'Ymd\\TG:i:s'
  - 'xmlrpcCompact' == 'Ymd\\tGis'
  - 'wddx' == 'Y-n-j\\TG:i:s'
- 'constants'

  - 'AMERICAN' == 'F j Y'
  - 'AMERICANSHORT' == 'm/d/Y'
  - 'AMERICANSHORTWTIME' == 'm/d/Y h:i:sA'
  - 'ATOM' == 'Y-m-d\\TH:i:sP'
  - 'COOKIE' == 'l d-M-Y H:i:s T'
  - 'EUROPEAN' == 'j F Y'
  - 'EUROPEANSHORT' == 'd.m.Y'
  - 'EUROPEANSHORTWTIME' == 'd.m.Y H:i:s'
  - 'ISO8601' == 'Y-m-d\\TH:i:sO'
  - 'LEGAL' == 'j F Y'
  - 'RFC822' == 'D d M y H:i:s O'
  - 'RFC850' == 'l d-M-y H:i:s T'
  - 'RFC1036' == 'D d M y H:i:s O'
  - 'RFC1123' == 'D d M Y H:i:s O'
  - 'RFC2822' == 'D d M Y H:i:s O'
  - 'RFC3339' == 'Y-m-d\\TH:i:sP'
  - 'RSS' == 'D d M Y H:i:s O'
  - 'W3C' == 'Y-m-d\\TH:i:sP'
- 'pretty'

  - 'pretty-a' == 'g:i.sA l jS \\o\\f F Y'
  - 'pretty-b' == 'g:iA l jS \\o\\f F Y'
  - 'pretty-c' == 'n/d/Y g:iA'
  - 'pretty-d' == 'n/d/Y'
  - 'pretty-e' == 'F jS - g:ia'
  - 'pretty-f' == 'g:iA'

*As you may notice, you can use double `\` to escape a character.*

---

Comment: @KamranAhmed Almost 2 years and 40+ votes later, I'd say the effort was worth it. LoL. I've since expanded this class alot personally, but haven't uploaded as I was thinking most people would use that other js date plugin i see recommended, but I guess I should make it more "public" and add it up here.

Comment: moment.js is now the thing you would use these days

Comment: Above, there is a typo (that took me awhile to spot), it uses a variable "today" in the line: " dayOfMonth = today + "

Comment: "today + ( objToday.getDate() < 10) ? '0' + objToday.getDate() + domEnder : objToday.getDate() + domEnder" - JS is stupid language.

Comment: Its just 39 past noon and it prints 12:39 am.

Answer (score 226):

If you just want a date without time info, use:

```js
var today = new Date();
    today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

document.write(today);
```

Comment: This seems to be the only answer that actually answers the question. Everyone else answers on how to format a date as string.

Comment: I agree. Actually I wanted to write an answer similar to this one and then a small window popped up asking me whether I've read through all the answers. Since I've read only the top answers, I decided to check whether there are any correct answers and this one was the first correct answer.

Comment: This sets hours using UTC, which might not work for all use cases.

Comment: I also agree. Answers the question perfectly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 121):

Try this:

```js
var currentDate = new Date()
var day = currentDate.getDate()
var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
var year = currentDate.getFullYear()
document.write("<b>" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "</b>")
```

The result will be like

```
15/2/2012
```

Answer (score 69):

If you're looking for a lot more granular control over the date formats, I thoroughly recommend  checking out momentjs. Terrific library - and only 5KB.
http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Supports localization like a charm.

Comment: These days we use date-fns - it treats dates as Immutable (Moment mutates dates), is faster and is modular (just import what you need).

Comment: Six years after posting this momentjs has put on quite a bit of weight. You may want to check out https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs instead - I've had it described to me as "momentjs on a diet". Same simple API.

Answer (score 68):

```
var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US");
```

Also, you can call method `toLocaleDateString` with two parameters:

```
var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US", {
    "year": "numeric",
    "month": "numeric"
});
```

More about this method on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString).

Comment: Nice, works on Chrome. Unfortunately doesn't work on PhantomJS as of 22/4/2016

Comment: cool solution. should be on the top. `new Date().toLocaleDateString("de-de")` does the trick for me.

Comment: Use `new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US", {
    "year": "numeric", "day": "numeric", "month": "long",
});` if you need the month name instead of number.

Answer (score 64):

You can use moment.js: http://momentjs.com/

```js
var m = moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY");

document.write(m);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Moment is overkill for just getting the current date.

Comment: Or `moment().format("L")` to respect the current locale.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Actually, the Javascript base specification for DateTime is that bad.

Comment: If you already have momentjs imported in your project then this is the cleanest simplest answer.

Answer (score 58):

```js
var d = (new Date()).toString().split(' ').splice(1,3).join(' ');

document.write(d)
```

To break it down into steps:

1. `(new Date()).toString()` gives "Fri Jun 28 2013 15:30:18 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
2. `(new Date()).toString().split(' ')` divides the above string on each space and returns an array as follows: ["Fri", "Jun", "28", "2013", "15:31:14", "GMT-0700", "(PDT)"]
3. `(new Date()).toString().split(' ').splice(1,3).join(' ')` takes the second, third and fourth values from the above array, joins them with spaces, and returns a string "Jun 28 2013"

Comment: I needed a time in 00:00:00 and didn't want to rebuild it manually; step 2 gets me there perfectly. Kudos!

Comment: You can save some bytes by doing this: `Date().split(' ').splice(1,3).join(' ')`

Answer (score 52):

This works every time:

```js
    var now = new Date();
    var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var today = now.getFullYear() + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day);
    
    console.log(today);
```

Answer (score 52):

Most of the other answers are providing the date with time.
If you only need date.

```
new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0]
```

Output

```
[ '2021-02-08', '06:07:44.629Z' ]
```

If you want it in `/` format use `replaceAll`.

```
new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0].replaceAll("-", "/")
```

If you want other formats then best to use `momentjs`.

Comment: Thank you! I knew date had to have a string method, I don't know why everyone is parsing out days and months and years and concatenating.. Even if you wanted dashes:
    Date().toISOString().split('T')[0].replaceAll('/','-')

Comment: Yeah, maybe they had something else in mind.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for what's needed to set value in an input date, and this is it – it should be the most common use case!

Answer (score 51):

Cleaner, simpler version:

```
new Date().toLocaleString();
```

Result **varies** according to the user's **locale**:

> 2/27/2017, 9:15:41 AM

Answer (score 34):

If you are happy with YYYY-MM-DD format, this will do the job as well.

`new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]`

`2018-03-10`

Comment: Since the length is always fixed, we can use substring as well.
new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);

Might be a bit faster as well.

Answer (score 25):

You can use [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) library which extens Date object, thus you can have .today() method.

Comment: if you are using jquery ui with a datepicker, you can use $.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', new Date())

Answer (score 22):

Using the JavaScript built-in *Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()* (more options are in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)):

```js
const options = {
  month: '2-digit',
  day: '2-digit',
  year: 'numeric',
};

console.log(new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US', options)); // mm/dd/yyyy
```

We can get similar behavior using `Intl.DateTimeFormat` which has decent [browser support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_intl_datetimeformat_format). Similar to `toLocaleDateString()`, we can pass an object with [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#using_options):

```
const date = new Date('Dec 2, 2021') // Thu Dec 16 2021 15:49:39 GMT-0600
const options = {
  day: '2-digit',
  month: '2-digit',
  year: 'numeric',
}
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(date) // '12/02/2021'
```

Answer (score 21):

You can get the current date call the static method now like this:

```
var now = Date.now()
```

reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now

Comment: This was basically all I needed.

`var dtToday = new Date(date.now);`

Answer (score 20):

[Varun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19079030/1338062) does not account for [TimezoneOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset). Here is a version that does:

```
var d = new Date()
new Date(d.getTime() - d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000).toJSON().slice(0, 10) // 2015-08-11
```

The `TimezoneOffset` is minutes, while the Date constructor takes milliseconds, thus the multiplication by `60000`.

Answer (score 17):

As `toISOString()` will only return current UTC time , not local time. We have to make a date by using '.toString()' function to get date in `yyyy-MM-dd` format like

```js
document.write(new Date(new Date().toString().split('GMT')[0]+' UTC').toISOString().split('T')[0]);
```

**To get date and time into in `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` format**

```js
document.write(new Date(new Date().toString().split('GMT')[0]+' UTC').toISOString().split('.')[0]);
```

**To get date and time into in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format**

```js
document.write(new Date(new Date().toString().split('GMT')[0]+' UTC').toISOString().split('.')[0].replace('T',' '));
```

Answer (score 16):

The Shortest Answer is: `new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10)`

Comment: I was looking for a very simple seed function that changes regularly. This answer is a real treat.

Comment: don't use this it gets the previous date at 7am

Answer (score 15):

```
new Date().toDateString();
```

Result:

> "Wed Feb 03 2016"

Answer (score 14):

```
new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);
```

would work too

Answer (score 13):

If you want a simple `DD/MM/YYYY` format, I've just come up with this simple solution, although it doesn't prefix missing zeros.

```js
var d = new Date();
document.write( [d.getDate(), d.getMonth()+1, d.getFullYear()].join('/') );
```

Answer (score 13):

Try

```
`${Date()}`.slice(4,15)
```

```js
console.log( `${Date()}`.slice(4,15) )
```

We use here standard JS functionalities: [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) which is cast to string, and [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice). This is probably shortest solution which meet OP requirements (no time, only date)

Comment: Question is for javascript.

Comment: @JaydeepShil - this is javascript solution - if you don't believe run above snippet or copy-paste it to chrome console

Comment: Great and concise solution!! Thanks

Answer (score 12):

This is good to get a formatted date

```js
let date = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en", {year:"numeric", day:"2-digit", month:"2-digit"});
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 11):

**LATEST EDIT: 8/23/19**
The [date-fns](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns) library works much like [moment.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) but has a WAY smaller footprint. It lets you cherry pick which functions you want to include in your project so you don't have to compile the whole library to format today's date. If a minimal 3rd party lib isn't an option for your project, I endorse the accepted solution by Samuel Meddows up top.

**Preserving history below because it helped a few people. But for the record it's pretty hacky and liable to break without warning, as are most of the solutions on this post**

**EDIT 2/7/2017**
**A one-line JS solution:**

> tl;dr
>   `var todaysDate = new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString().slice(0,3).match(/[0-9]/i) ? new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString().split(' ')[0].split(',')[0] : new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString().split(' ')[1] + " " + new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString().split(' ')[2] + " " + new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString().split(' ')[3];`
>   
> edge, ff latest, & chrome return `todaysDate = "2/7/2017"` 
> "works"* in IE10+

**Explanation**

I found out that IE10 and IE Edge do things a bit differently.. go figure.
with `new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString()` as input,

IE10 returns:

```
"Tuesday, February 07, 2017 2:58:25 PM"
```

I could write a big long function and FTFY. But **you really ought to use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for this stuff.** My script merely cleans this up and gives you the *expanded* traditional US notation: `> todaysDate = "March 06, 2017"`

IE EDGE returns:

```
"‎2‎/‎7‎/‎2017‎ ‎2‎:‎59‎:‎27‎ ‎PM"
```

Of course it couldn't be that easy. **Edge's date string has invisible "•" characters between each visible one.** So not only will we now be checking if the first character is a number, but the first 3 characters, since it turns out that any single character in the whole date range will eventually be a dot or a slash at some point. So to keep things simple, just [.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) the first three chars (tiny buffer against future shenanigans) and then check for numbers. It should probably be noted that these invisible dots could potentially persist in your code. I'd maybe dig into that if you've got bigger plans than just printing this string to your view.

**∴ updated one-liner:**

```
var todaysDate = new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString().slice(0,3).match(/[0-9]/i) ? new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString().split(' ')[0].split(',')[0] : new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString().split(' ')[1] + " " + new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString().split(' ')[2] + " " + new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString().split(' ')[3];
```

That sucks to read. How about:

```
var dateString = new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString();
var todaysDate = dateString.slice(0,3).match(/[0-9]/i) ? dateString.split(' ')[0].split(',')[0] : dateString.split(' ')[1] + " " + dateString.split(' ')[2] + " " + dateString.split(' ')[3];
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I've got a one-liner for you:

```
new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString().split(', ')[0];
```

and `[1]` will give you the time of day.

Answer (score 10):

A straightforward way to pull that off (whilst considering your current time zone it taking advantage of the ISO yyyy-mm-dd format) is:

```
let d = new Date().toISOString().substring(0,19).replace("T"," ") // "2020-02-18 16:41:58"
```

Usually, this is a pretty all-purpose compatible date format and you can convert it to pure date value if needed:

```
Date.parse(d); // 1582044297000
```

Answer (score 9):

You can checkout this

```
var today = new Date();
today = parseInt(today.getMonth()+1)+'/'+today.getDate()+'/'+today.getFullYear()+"\nTime : "+today.getHours()+":"+today.getMinutes()+":"+today.getSeconds();
document.write(today);
```

And see the documentation for Date() constructor.
[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

[Get Current Date Month Year in React js](https://web-tuts.com/get-current-date-month-year-in-react-js/)

Answer (score 8):

You can use this

```
<script>
function my_curr_date() {      
    var currentDate = new Date()
    var day = currentDate.getDate();
    var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
    var my_date = month+"-"+day+"-"+year;
    document.getElementById("dateField").value=my_date;    
}
</script>
```

The HTML is

```
<body onload='return my_curr_date();'>
    <input type='text' name='dateField' id='dateField' value='' />
</body>
```

Answer (score 8):

If by "current date" you are thinking about "today", then this trick may work for you:

```
> new Date(3600000*Math.floor(Date.now()/3600000))
2020-05-07T07:00:00.000Z
```

This way you are getting today [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) instance with time 0:00:00.

The principle of operation is very simple: we take the current timestamp and divide it for 1 day expressed in milliseconds. We will get a fraction. By using [Math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor), we get rid of the fraction, so we get an integer. Now if we multiply it back by one day (again - in milliseconds), we get a date timestamp with the time exactly at the beginning of the day.

```js
> now = Date.now()
1588837459929
> daysInMs = now/3600000
441343.73886916664
> justDays = Math.floor(daysInMs)
441343
> today = justDays*3600000
1588834800000
> new Date(today)
2020-05-07T07:00:00.000Z
```

Clean and simple.

Comment: Where is the explanation of how this answer works and why you feel it is good advice?

Comment: I don't understand from where came this sudden attack? I don't see that you asked that question to other answers? May I know why I have been awarded this way?

Comment: I don't understand why you feel this is an attack.  Yes, I did blow the whistle on (several) other code-only answers.  You have the ability to edit your post.  Please improve it with the intention to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Comment: It is hard not to get the impression of an attack, after rough and high-hat imperative sentence. I will gladly improve my answer, but please next time don't assume that you have right to order people around. I really appreciate your care and your time to make Stackoverflow a better place, but believe me that nobody will want to cooperate with you if you will be treating people from high. Like sentence "Could you provide the explanation of how this answer works and why you feel it is good advice?" sound so much better in my eyes then "Where is...". Do you understand what I'm talking about?

Comment: I could answer the same: is this your way of self-appreciation? :) But I'm not going to continue this conversation because I see that it does not lead to anything.

Answer (score 8):

This does a lot:

```js
    var today = new Date();
    var date = today.getFullYear() + '/' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + today.getDate();
    document.write(date);
```

Where **today.getFullYear()** gets the current year.

**today.getMonth()+1** gets the current month.

And **today.getDate()** gets today's date.

All of this is concatenated with '/'.

Comment: Code-only answers are low-value on Stack Overflow because they do a very poor job of educating/empowering the OP and thousands of future researchers.

Comment: Why today.getMonth()+1 ?

Answer (score 8):

```
// Try this simple way

const today = new Date();
let date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
console.log(date);
```

Comment: Answer's are great. But for best practices, please provide an explanation. You only posting code makes the OP and future commers copy and paste your answer without understanding the logic behind the answer. Please provide an answer with some explanation. Thank You!

Answer (score 7):

If you are using jQuery. Try this one liner :

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date());
```

Here is the convention for formatting the date

- d - day of month (no leading zero)
- dd - day of month (two digit)
- o - day of the year (no leading zeros)
- oo - day of the year (three digit)
- D - day name short
- DD - day name long
- m - month of year (no leading zero)
- mm - month of year (two digit)
- M - month name short
- MM - month name long
- y - year (two digit)
- yy - year (four digit)

Here is the reference for jQuery [datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Answer (score 7):

If you’re looking to format into a string.

```
statusUpdate = "time " + new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleTimeString();
```

Output: "time 11:30:53 AM"

Comment: Why the Date.now()?  

    var x = new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleTimeString(); 
    var y = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

    x === y

Answer (score 5):

```
var dateTimeToday = new Date();
var dateToday = new Date(
    dateTimeToday.getFullYear(), 
    (dateTimeToday.getMonth() + 1) /*Jan = 0! */, 
    dateTimeToday.getDate(), 
    0, 
    0, 
    0, 
    0);
```

Comment: Do we really need another answer like that?

Comment: I did not find this method in any of the answers so added it

Comment: This is a duplicate of this earlier posted and higher voted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9290264/2943403

Answer (score 5):

What's the big deal with this..   The cleanest way to do this is

`var currentDate=new Date().toLocaleString().slice(0,10);`

Comment: It would return mistakes, like this `3/4/2018, `, better to use `new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10)`.

Comment: This is perfect for simply getting a date for view or for info on console log or for UI.  Better for me without the `.slice(0,10)`

Answer (score 5):

So many complicated answers...

Just use `new Date()` and if you need it as a string, simply use `new Date().toISOString()`

Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

Pretty Print The Date Like This.

> June 1st, 2015 11:36:48 AM

https://gist.github.com/Gerst20051/7d72693f722bbb0f6b58

Answer (score 4):

This may help you

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.getDate()+'/'+(date.getMonth()+1)+'/'+date.getFullYear());
```

This will print current date in dd/MM/yyyy format

Answer (score 4):

## TL;DR

Most of the answers found here are correct **only** if you need the current time that's on your local machine (client) which is a source that often cannot be considered reliable (it will probably differ from another system).

Reliable sources are:

- Web server's clock (but make sure that it's updated)
- Time APIs & CDNs

## Details

A method called on the `Date` instance will return a value based on the local time of your machine.

Further details can be found in "MDN web docs": [JavaScript Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

For your convenience, I've added a relevant note from their docs:

> (...) the basic methods to fetch the date and time or its components all work in the local (i.e. host system) time zone and offset.

Another source mentioning this is: [JavaScript date and time object](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptdate.php)

> it is important to note that if someone's clock is off by a few hours or they are in a different time zone, then the Date object will create a different times from the one created on your own computer.

Some reliable sources that you can use are:

- Your web server's clock (first check if it's properly set)
- Time APIs & CDNs:

  - https://timezonedb.com/api
  - http://worldtimeapi.org
  - http://worldclockapi.com
  - http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html
  - Other related APIs: https://www.programmableweb.com/category/time/api

But if accuracy is not important for your use case or if you simply need the date to be relative to local machine's time then you can safely use Javascript's `Date` basic methods like `Date.now()`.

Answer (score 4):

In Australia, I prefer to get DD/MM/YYYY using this

```
(new Date()).toISOString().slice(0, 10).split("-").reverse().join("/")
```

Comment: Actually returns DD/MM/YYYY , without any details or unwanted info.

Comment: perfect what I wanted

Answer (score 3):

I think this is an old question but the easiest way would be the following:

```
var date = new Date();
var TimeStamp = date.toLocaleString();

function CurrentTime(){
  alert(TimeStamp);
}
```

This will grab the current time, pass it to a string based on location and then you can call the function CurrentTime to display the time.  This would be, to me, the most effective way to get a time stamp for something.

Comment: This will return data+time, eg. '2018-4-6 16:20:22', and the question is how to get date only.

Answer (score 3):

This is my current favorite, because it's both flexible and modular. It's a collection of (at least) three simple functions:

```
/**
 * Returns an array with date / time information
 * Starts with year at index 0 up to index 6 for milliseconds
 * 
 * @param {Date} date   date object. If falsy, will take current time.
 * @returns {[]}
 */
getDateArray = function(date) {
    date = date || new Date();
    return [
        date.getFullYear(),
        exports.pad(date.getMonth()+1, 2),
        exports.pad(date.getDate(), 2),
        exports.pad(date.getHours(), 2),
        exports.pad(date.getMinutes(), 2),
        exports.pad(date.getSeconds(), 2),
        exports.pad(date.getMilliseconds(), 2)
    ];
};
```

Here's the pad function:

```
 /**
 * Pad a number with n digits
 *
 * @param {number} number   number to pad
 * @param {number} digits   number of total digits
 * @returns {string}
 */
exports.pad = function pad(number, digits) {
    return new Array(Math.max(digits - String(number).length + 1, 0)).join(0) + number;
};
```

Finally I can either build my date string by hand, or use a simple functions to do it for me:

```
/**
 * Returns nicely formatted date-time
 * @example 2015-02-10 16:01:12
 *
 * @param {object} date
 * @returns {string}
 */
exports.niceDate = function(date) {
    var d = exports.getDateArray(date);
    return d[0] + '-' + d[1] + '-' + d[2] + ' ' + d[3] + ':' + d[4] + ':' + d[5];
};

/**
 * Returns a formatted date-time, optimized for machines
 * @example 2015-02-10_16-00-08
 *
 * @param {object} date
 * @returns {string}
 */
exports.roboDate = function(date) {
    var d = exports.getDateArray(date);
    return d[0] + '-' + d[1] + '-' + d[2] + '_' + d[3] + '-' + d[4] + '-' + d[5];
};
```

Answer (score 2):

### The basics

If you're happy with the format `Sun Jan 24 2016 21:23:07 GMT+0100 (CET)`, you could just use this code :

```
var today = new Date();
```

### Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()

If you want to format your output, consider using [**`Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) :

```
var today = new Date().toLocaleDateString('de-DE', {     
    weekday: 'long', 
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric'
});
```

If you executed that code today (january 24ᵗʰ, 2016) on a modern browser, it would produce the string `Sonntag, 24. Januar 2016`. Older browsers may generate a different result, though, as eg. IE<11 doesn't support locales or options arguments.

### Going custom

If [**`Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) isn't flexible enough to fulfill whatever need you may have, you might want to consider creating a custom Date object that looks like this :

```
var DateObject = (function() {
    var monthNames = [
      "January", "February", "March",
      "April", "May", "June", "July",
      "August", "September", "October",
      "November", "December"
    ];
    var date = function(str) {
        this.set(str);
    };
    date.prototype = {
        set : function(str) {
            var dateDef = str ? new Date(str) : new Date();
            this.day = dateDef.getDate();
            this.dayPadded = (this.day < 10) ? ("0" + this.day) : "" + this.day;
            this.month = dateDef.getMonth() + 1;
            this.monthPadded = (this.month < 10) ? ("0" + this.month) : "" + this.month;
            this.monthName = monthNames[this.month - 1];
            this.year = dateDef.getFullYear();
        }
    };
    return date;
})();
```

If you included that code and executed `new DateObject()` today (january 24ᵗʰ, 2016), it would produce an object with the following properties :

```
day: 24
dayPadded: "24"
month: 1
monthPadded: "01"
monthName: "January"
year: 2016
```

Answer (score 2):

2.39KB minified. One file. https://github.com/rhroyston/clock-js

Just trying to help...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a lot more granular control over the date formats, I thoroughly recommend checking out [date-FNS](https://date-fns.org/docs/Getting-Started).

It is a terrific library and is much smaller than [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). It's a function-based approach that makes it much faster than other class-based libraries. It provides a large number of operations needed over dates.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function() { var d = new Date(); return new Date(d - d % 86400000); })()
```

Comment: Where did `86400000` come from?

Comment: It's the number of milliseconds in a day: 60secs x 60mins x 24hours x 1000 - you'd probably recognize it too if you've had to mess a lot with dates in JavaScript...

Comment: The point is: There should be an explanation with every answer (in the answer) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my DATE API given below for everyday use of date formatting along with getting current date, yesterday etc. 
How to use 
  e.g.

```
 var dt = new Date();  
       /// ANY DATE YOU WANT --  dt = new Date(""July 21, 1983 01:15:00"")

       dateObj = dt.getFormattedDate();

       alert( dateObj.isToday() );
       alert( dateObj.todayDay() );
       alert( dateObj.monthNameDayYear() );
```

---

```
(function () {

    fnDateProcessor = function () {
        var that = this;

        return {

            yyyymmdd: function (separator) {
                var fdate = this.formatDate(true, true) ,
                    separator = separator ? separator : "-";
                return fdate.year + separator + fdate.month + separator + fdate.day;
            },

            monthNameDayYear: function () {
                var fdate = this.formatDate(true, true);
                return fdate.monthName + " " + fdate.day + ", " + fdate.year;
            },

            ddmmyyyy: function (separator) {
                var fdate = this.formatDate(true, true) ,
                    separator = separator ? separator : "/";
                return fdate.day + separator + fdate.month + separator + fdate.year;
            },

            meridianTime: function () {
                var fdate = this.formatDate();
                return fdate.hour + ":" + fdate.minute + " " + fdate.meridian;
            },

            monthDay: function (separator) {

                var fdate = this.formatDate();
                separator = checkSeparator(separator);
                return fdate.monthName.substring(0, 3) + separator + fdate.day;

            },

            weekMonthDayYear: function () {
                var fdate = this.formatDate();
                //separator = checkSeparator(separator);

                return fdate.weekDay + " " + fdate.monthName.substring(0, 3) +
                    fdate.day + " ," + fdate.year;
            },

            timeZoneInclusive: function () {

                return new Date(that);
            },

            todayDay: function () { return new Date().getDate(); },
            todayMonth: function () { return new Date().getMonth() + 1; },
            dateDay: function () { return this.formatDate().day; },
            dateMonth: function () { return this.formatDate().month; },
            isToday: function () { return this.sameDate(new Date()); },
            isYesterday: function () {
                d = new Date(); d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
                return this.sameDate(d);
            },

            formatDate: function () {
                var zeroPaddedMnth = true, zeroPaddedDay = false,
                    zeroPaddedHr = false, zeroPaddedMin = true;
                // Possible to take Options arg that overide / merge to defaults

                var monthNames = [
                    "January", "February", "March",
                    "April", "May", "June", "July",
                    "August", "September", "October",
                    "November", "December"
                ];
                var weekDays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

                var day = getFormattedDay(that.getDate(), zeroPaddedDay);
                var monthIndex = that.getMonth();
                var month = getFormattedMonth(monthIndex + 1, zeroPaddedMnth);
                var year = that.getFullYear();
                var wkDay = that.getDay();
                var hour = getFormattedHour(that.getHours(), zeroPaddedHr);
                var minute = getFormattedMinute(that.getMinutes(), zeroPaddedMin);
                var meridian = getMeridian(that.getHours());

                return {
                    "day": day, "monthName": monthNames[monthIndex], "month": month,
                    "weekDay": weekDays[wkDay], "year": year, "hour": hour, "minute": minute,
                    "meridian": meridian
                };
            },

            compareDate: function (d2) {     /// validates if caller is less than argument                            
                d2 = _isString(d2) ? new Date(d2) : d2;

                return !this.sameDate(d2)
                    && typeof d2 != "number"
                    ? that < d2 : false;
            },

            sameDate: function (d) {
                return that.getFullYear() === d.getFullYear()
                    && that.getDate() === d.getDate()
                    && that.getMonth() === d.getMonth();
            },

            dateAfter: function (separator) {
                var fdate = this.formatDate();
                var separator = separator ? separator : "-";
                return fdate.year + separator + fdate.month + separator + (fdate.day + 1);
            }

        };

    };


    function _isString(obj) {
        var toString = Object.prototype.toString;
        return toString.call(obj) == '[object String]';
    }

    function checkSeparator(separator) {
        // NOT GENERIC ... NEEDS REVISION
        switch (separator) {
            case " ": sep = separator; break;
            case ",": sep = " ,"; break;
            default:
                sep = " "; break;
        }

        return sep;
    }

    function getFormattedHour(h, zeroPadded) {
        h = h % 12;
        h = h ? h : 12;    //  12 instead of 00
        return zeroPadded ? addZero(h) : h;
    }

    function getFormattedMinute(m, zeroPadded) {

        return zeroPadded ? addZero(m) : m;
    }

    function getFormattedDay(dd, zeroPadded) {

        return zeroPadded ? addZero(dd) : dd;
    }
    function getFormattedMonth(mm, zeroPadded) {

        return zeroPadded ? addZero(mm) : mm;
    }

    function getMeridian(hr) {

        return hr >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
    }

    function addZero(i) {
        if (i < 10) {
            i = "0" + i;
        }
        return i;
    }


    Date.prototype.getFormattedDate = fnDateProcessor;

} ());
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for people looking for a date with a ISO-8601-like format and with the time zone.

It's pure JavaScript for those who don't want to include any date library.

```
var date = new Date();
var timeZone = date.toString();
// Get timezone ('GMT+0200')
var timeZoneIndex = timeZone.indexOf('GMT');
// Cut optional string after timezone ('(heure de Paris)')
var optionalTimeZoneIndex = timeZone.indexOf('(');
if(optionalTimeZoneIndex != -1){
    timeZone = timeZone.substring(timeZoneIndex, optionalTimeZoneIndex);
}
else{
    timeZone = timeZone.substring(timeZoneIndex);
}
// Get date with JSON format ('2019-01-23T16:28:27.000Z')
var formattedDate = new Date(date.getTime() - (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toJSON();
// Cut ms
formattedDate = formattedDate.substring(0,formattedDate.indexOf('.'));
// Add timezone
formattedDate = formattedDate + ' ' + timeZone;
console.log(formattedDate);
```

Print something like this in the console:

> 2019-01-23T17:12:52 GMT+0100

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n9mszhjc/4/

Answer (score 1):

To get just the date, then it is built in to JavaScript:

```
new Date();
```

If you are looking for date formatting and you are anyway using the [Kendo jQuery UI](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-jquery-ui) library for your site, then I suggest using the built-in [Kendo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telerik#Controls_Suite) function:

```
kendo.toString(new Date(), "yyMMdd"); // Or any other typical date format
```

For a full list of supported formats, [see here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/globalization/intl/dateformatting).

Answer (score 1):

Try [Date.js](https://github.com/Parking-Master/Date.js)

Milliseconds

```
date.js.millisecond(); // 0.00
```

Seconds

```
date.js.second(); // 58
```

Minutes

```
date.js.minute(); // 31
```

Hours

```
date.js.hour(); // 6  (PM)
```

Days

```
date.js.day(); // Monday
```

Weeks

```
date.js.week(); // (Week Of the Month / WOM) => 2
```

Month

```
date.js.month(); // (Month) => November
```

TLM (Three-Letter-Month)

```
date.js.tlmonth(); // (Month) => Dec
```

Year

```
date.js.year(); // (Year / String: "") => "2021"
```

Season

```
date.js.season(); // (Fall / Season: seasons) => "fall"
```

Current Time in AM/PM

```
date.js.time(); // (Time / Zone: "PDT/EDT etc.") => 10:04 AM
```

Comment: Not [autumn](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/autumn#Noun)?

Comment: It’s supposed to be in human readable form. You can change that though by using `data.js.season() == “fall” ? “autumn” : date.js.season()`

Answer (score 0):

With the ability to render in a custom format and using the month name in different locales:

```
const locale = 'en-us';
const d = new Date(date);

const day = d.getDate();
const month = d.toLocaleString(locale, { month: 'long' });
const year = d.getFullYear();

const time = d.toLocaleString(locale, { hour12: false, hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric'});

return `${month} ${day}, ${year} @ ${time}`; // May 5, 2019 @ 23:41
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only require the string representation, then simply use:

```
Date();
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a date format like this **09-Apr-2020**

```
function getDate(){
  var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

  var today = new Date();
  var dd    = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  var mm    = months[today.getMonth()];
  var yyyy  = today.getFullYear();

  today = dd + "-" + mm + "-" + yyyy;
  return today;
}

getDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

My way

```
let dateString = new Date().toLocaleString().split(',').find(() => true);
```

Answer (score 0):

A library is not needed, and the time zone is taken into consideration.

Because sometimes you will need to calculate it on the server. This can be server time zone independent.

```js
const currentTimezoneOffset = 8; // UTC+8:00 time zone, change it

Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
    return [
        this.getFullYear(),
        (this.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, '0'), // getMonth() is zero-based
        this.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')
    ].join('-');
};

function getTodayDateStr() {
  const d = new Date();
  // console.log(d);
  const d2 = new Date(d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() + currentTimezoneOffset * 60) * 60 * 1000);
  // console.log(d2, d2.yyyymmdd());
  return d2.yyyymmdd();
}

console.log(getTodayDateStr());
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to automatically retrieve the browser's locale name and pass it as the first argument of `toLocaleString()`, so that you can pass other options:

```js
// Get locale name
function getLang() {
  if (navigator.languages != undefined)
    return navigator.languages[0];
  return navigator.language;
}

// Get the current datetime with format yyyy-MM-ddThhmmss
const time = new Date().toLocaleString(getLang(), {
  hour12: false ,
  year: 'numeric',
  month: '2-digit',
  day: '2-digit',
  hour: "numeric",
  minute: "numeric",
  second: "numeric"
}).replaceAll('/', '-').replaceAll(':', '').replaceAll(' ', 'T')

console.log("locale:", getLang())
console.log(time)
```

The result may looks like:

```
locale: zh-TW
2022-09-13T171642
```

When you change your browser's locale setting, the time and date (if needed) will change too.

Answer (score 0):

This is only 2 lines.

```js
let date = new Date().toLocaleDateString()
            .split("/")
            .map((d) => (d.length <= 1 ? "0" + d : d));

let newDate = `${date[1]}/${date[0]}/${date[2]}`;

console.log(newDate); // => dd/mm/yyyy
```

Answer (score 0):

With the upcoming Temporal API (stage 3), you can use [`Temporal.PlainDateTime`](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/plaindatetime.html).

For example, for the current date and time in the ISO 8601 calendar you can use the `plainDateTimeISO` method on [`Temporal.Now`](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/now.html)

```js
const datetime = Temporal.Now.plainDateTimeISO();
console.log(datetime.toString());
```

Similarly, for only the date you can use [`Temporal.PlainDate`](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/plaindate.html).

```js
const date = Temporal.Now.plainDateISO();
console.log(date.toString());
```

And similarly for only the time you can use [`Temporal.PlainTime`](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/plaintime.html).

```js
const time = Temporal.Now.plainTimeISO();
console.log(time.toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution uses string literals. [Find out more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)...

```js
// Declare Date as d
var d = new Date()

// Inline formatting of Date
const exampleOne = `${d.getDay()}-${d.getMonth() + 1}-${d.getFullYear()}`
// January is 0 so +1 is required

// With Breaklines and Operators
const exampleTwo = `+++++++++++
With Break Lines and Arithmetic Operators Example
Year on newline: ${d.getFullYear()}
Year minus(-) 30 years: ${d.getFullYear() - 30}
You get the idea...
+++++++++++`

console.log('=============')
console.log(exampleOne)
console.log('=============')

console.log(exampleTwo)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this and you can adjust the date format accordingly:

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd;
}
if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm;
}

var myDate = dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yyyy;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Date.prototype.toLocalFullDateStringYYYYMMDDHHMMSS = function () {
if (this != null && this != undefined) {
    let str = this.getFullYear();
    str += "-" + round(this.getMonth() + 1);
    str += "-" + round(this.getDate());
    str += "T";
    str += round(this.getHours());
    str += ":" + round(this.getMinutes());
    str += ":" + round(this.getSeconds());
    return str;
} else {
    return this;
}

function round(n){
    if(n < 10){
        return "0" + n;
    }
    else return n;
}};
```

Answer (score -6):

Important note: do not use: `var today = new Date();`

*But* `var dateToday = new Date();`, for example, as `var today` does not indicate anything.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32202583)