# php Date Conversion to javaScript

Tags: javascript, php

Needs help in rewriting this php code in JavaScript

```
$date='20170721';
$stamps = strtotime($date);
$newdate = date('d M Y',$stamps);
$data = explode(' ', $newdate);
echo $data[0].' '.strtoupper($data[1]).' '.$data[2];
//output 2017 JUL 21
```

I am new in JavaScript this is what i have done so far

```
var date='20170721';
varstamps = strtotime($date);
var newdate = date('d M Y',$stamps);
var data = explode(' ', $newdate);
$data[0].' '.strtoupper($data[1]).' '.$data[2];
```

Comment: Try `echo $data[2].' '.strtoupper($data[1]).' '.$data[0];`

Comment: var date='20170721'; varstamps = strtotime($date);

var newdate = date('d M Y',$stamps);

var data = explode(' ', $newdate);

$data[0].' '.strtoupper($data[1]).' '.$data[2];



This is not working because '$' is not recognize by jquery as variable.

Comment: Do you want just date to display or want other function?

Comment: Please note that the OP wants a JavaScript code, so you can't use PHP functions in it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution

```js
var date = '20170721'; 
var year = date.slice(0,4), 
month = date.slice(4,6), 
day = date.slice(-2);

// create new Date obj
date = new Date(year, month, day);

// format using toLocaleDateString
console.log(new Date(year, month, day).toLocaleDateString('en-GB'));

// custom format
console.log(date.getFullYear() + ' ' + (date.getMonth()) + ' ' + date.getDate())


//output 2017 JUL 21
```

Answer (score 1):

For better Result you can user `https://momentjs.com/` Moment js

include moment js using 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>`

`var date = '20170721';
moment(date).format('YYYY MMM DD');`

Answer (score 0):

Php :

```
$date='20170721'; 
$stamps = strtotime($date);
```

Javascript :

```
var idate = 1500588000; // unix timestamp returned from php ($stamps variable)
  var jdate = new Date(idate * 1000);
var day = jdate.getDate();
var month = jdate.getMonth();
var year = jdate.getYear();
var fulldate = jdate.toDateString();
```

Reference : [Javascript Date - set just the date, ignoring time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847806/javascript-date-set-just-the-date-ignoring-time)

Answer (score 0):

Currently i dont think javascript supports date conversions as this, but heres a work around

```js
    
var str='20170721';
var datee=str.slice(0,4)+'-'+str.slice(4,6)+'-'+str.slice(6,8);

var date = new Date(datee);
var newDate = date.toString('yyyy MMMM dd');
console.log(newDate);
// Or you can decide to do this without any external library
var num =parseInt(str.slice(4,6));
 var month='';
      switch(num)
      {
        case 0:
          month="January";
          break;
        case 1:
          month="February";
          break;
        case 2:
          month="March";
          break;
        case 3:
          month="April";
          break;
        case 4:
          month="May";
          break;
        case 5:
          month="June";
          break;
        case 6:
          month="July";
          break;
        case 7:
          month="August";
          break;
        case 8:
          month="September";
          break;
        case 9:
          month="October";
          break;
        case 10:
          month="November";
          break;
        case 11:
          month="December";
          break;
        default:
          month="Invalid month";
      }
console.log(str.slice(0,4)+' '+month+' '+str.slice(4,6));
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datejs/1.0/date.min.js"></script>
```