# Compare if 2 dates are the same in javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```js
var beginningTime = moment('1635750314812', 'YYYY/MM/DD'); // Today date
var endTime = moment(undefined, 'YYYY/MM/DD') // Today date
console.log(beginningTime.isSame(endTime)); //expect true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I am using moment js to get if 2 date are the same using the above pattern. But now i get false instead of true. How to solve the issue?

Comment: How is 1635750314812 in any way YYYY/MM/DD?!

Comment: @deceze took the words out of my mouth

Comment: @deceze, i don't understand what  you mean

Comment: `moment('1635750314812', 'YYYY/MM/DD')` means *parse `1635750314812` assuming it is in `YYYY/MM/DD` format*. Which it's clearly not.

Comment: `'YYYY/MM/DD'` is supposed to inform Moment about the format of the first argument. `moment('1635750314812', 'YYYY/MM/DD')` means : "Hey Moment, I'm informing you that `'1635750314812'` is in format `'YYYY/MM/DD')`. Moment is like 'Wat?' and produces an invalid Moment object. Log it, it says `_isValid:false`.

Comment: @deceze, how to change the code, could you help please? how to compare these 2 days?

Comment: Perhaps look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847806/javascript-date-set-just-the-date-ignoring-time. If you insist on using moment.js: moment(<timestamp>).format("YYYY/MM/DD") should be used.

Comment: @deceze, created something like this `const test = moment(moment('1635750314812').format('YYYY/MM/DD')).isSame(moment(undefined).format('YYYY/MM/DD'))
console.log(test);` , but anyway i get false.

Comment: @AgentM, created something like this const test = moment(moment('1635750314812').format('YYYY/MM/DD')).isSame(moment(undefined).format('YYYY/MM/DD')) console.log(test); , but anyway i get false.

Comment: `moment(moment())'`? `moment(undefined)` ? Do you feel any of this is right?

Comment: @JeremyThille, `console.log(moment(undefined).format('YYYY/MM/DD')); ` returns today's date. What do you mean?

Comment: But why do you add `undefined`? `moment()` returns today's date. Also why `moment( moment() )`?

Comment: I think they intend to create an object containing only the `Date` information from a `timestamp` and try to see if that `Date` is equal to the date of `now`. You could do something like `moment(moment(1635750314812).format('YYYY/MM/DD')).isSame(moment(moment().format('YYYY/MM/DD'))`, but it quickly gets quite ugly. There are probably better ways to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of formatting the beginningTime and endTime separately, you should take a look at the 'granularity' argument for [isSame()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/).

I made a few adjustments to your code for it to work, and also look cleaner.

```js
var beginningTime = moment(1635750314812); // Today date (from timestamp)
var endTime = moment() // Today date
console.log(beginningTime.isSame(endTime, 'day')); //expect true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

It first simply creates a `moment` of your timestamp and a `moment` of right now, whenever now is.
Then it will compare the two `moment`s with a granularity of a day, effectively checking if the day and everything bigger (month, year) is the same.