# JavaScript to allow only current and future dates..?

Tags: javascript

i need a java script to validate the text box which needs to allow only current and future dates.This is a text box and i am validating it on blur.
text box property :statingOn

written java script like below

```
function pastDateValidation()
{
    var d=document.getElementById("startingOn").value;
        if(new Date(d) < new Date())
    {
        alert(d);
        document.getElementById("startingOn").value="";
    }

}
```

it is validating the past dates but not the current date.I require the date from current to future.

if any one have th idea please share ur inputs.Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does your input look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing date part only without comparing time in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698725/comparing-date-part-only-without-comparing-time-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to discard the time portion of the current date.  `new Date()` is the current date **and time**.  Since your entered date has no time portion it is defaulting to midnight, which is before the current time, even though the dates are the same.  instead, clear the time portion from the current date:

```
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the date object is past date. 
The date.js library is quite handy for such things. It comes with bunch of functions which you can use.

```
function isPastDate(value) {
        var now = new Date;
        var target = new Date(value);

        if (target.getFullYear() < now.getFullYear()) {
            return true;
        } else if (target.getMonth() < now.getMonth()) {
            return true;
        } else if (target.getDate() <= now.getDate()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```