# Javascript to calculate whether given date is current date or future date?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a date picker I want to restrict input to prevent dates in the past. I used the JavaScript below but it's failing in certain conditions.

```
 function isPastDate(value) {
        var now = new Date;
        var target = new Date(value);

        if (target.getFullYear() < now.getFullYear()) {
            return true;
        } else if (target.getMonth() < now.getMonth()) {
            return true;
        } else if (target.getDate() < now.getDate()) {
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: In which conditions does it fail?

Comment: You are over complicating a simple thing `console.log(now > target)`

Comment: Someone copied the answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344318/javascript-to-allow-only-current-and-future-dates ??

Comment: @epascarello ya i followd that one and got failed.

Comment: Failed how? Explain how it fails...

Comment: @epascarello  :if user gave 03/13/2014 it compare with current date. when comparing date it gets failed hence 13 less then 18.

Comment: @MarkWalters if user gave 03/13/2014 it compare with current date. when comparing date it gets failed hence 13 less then 18.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As epascarello stated, simply compare both dates:

```
function isPastDate(value) {
    return new Date() > new Date(value);
}
```

This happens because the date is measured in milliseconds since Jan 1st 1970 (correct me if I'm wrong), so what is really happening is a comparison between two long numbers.

Comment: If you want to use this at a later time you could use a time stamp.
If not, this method works fine.
See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893083/convert-normal-date-to-unix-timestamp) for JavaScript time stamps.

Answer (score 1):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305259/check-if-date-is-in-the-past-javascript):

```
var selectedDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
var now = new Date();
if (selectedDate < now) {
  // selected date is in the past
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your function is logically wrong, and doesn't check after if the years are actually the same before testing the months, same goes to months and days.
You can try:

```
   function isPastDate(value) {
    var now = new Date;
    var target = new Date(value);

    if (target.getFullYear() < now.getFullYear()) {
        return true;
    } else if (target.getFullYear() === now.getFullYear())
        if (target.getMonth() < now.getMonth()) {
            return true;
        } else if (target.getMonth() === now.getMonth()) {
            if (target.getDate() < now.getDate()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Hope that helps