# JQuery Date Check

Tags: jquery

How do I check if a preset date (Sept. 13, 2013) is equal to the current date in JQuery - and then run an script if that's true. Here's the code I have right now, but it doesn't work. Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    var x = $("#third").position();
    var date = new Date();
    var today = new Date(2013,09,13);
    $("#dot").hide();
    if (y > (x.top - 50) && date == today) {
     $("#dot").show();
        $("#dot").addClass(
            "animation");
    }
    else {
        $("#dot").removeClass(
            "animation");
    }
});</script>
```

Comment: This is not necessarily related to jQuery

Comment: Animating an object in css if you scroll past a certain div and if the preset date is equal to the current date.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing date part only without comparing time in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698725/comparing-date-part-only-without-comparing-time-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because Date stores both date and time. When You write `new Date(2013, 09, 13)`, the value is equals to the midnigth of that day (so the time is 00:00:00 and when You write `new Date()`, the value is set current date and time, so it's true that's those two are not equal ;).

To solve this, you can change line:

```
if (y > (x.top - 50) && date == today) {
```

into

```
var tomorrow = new Date(2013, 09, 14);
tomorrow.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
if (y > (x.top - 50) && date > today && date < tomorrow) {
...
```

or just change

```
var date = new Date();
var today = new Date(2013,09,13);
```

into

```
var date = new Date();
date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
var today = new Date(2013,09,13);
```

to set current time to midnight, as described in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698725/comparing-date-part-only-without-comparing-time-in-javascript). That link helped me to find the answer :).

Comment: Ohh, is there a way to use Date without the time component?

Answer (score 0):

your date object contains time value as well, hence it will never match with the preset date.
You need to trim off the time part prior to compare.

```
var date = new Date();
   date.setDate(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDay());
var today = new Date(2013,09,13)
```

then compare

```
if(date == today )
{
 alert(true);
}
else
{
alert(false);
}
```