# how to convert value datetime to datepicker in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, datepicker, datetimepicker

i want to ask about convert datetimepicker to datepicker, i have value datetime, and i want to convert date ? how to convert that? this is my value

2013-11-29 10:12 to 29-11-2013

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698725/comparing-date-part-only-without-comparing-time-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date("2013-11-29 10:12");  //parse the date
var mon = date.getMonth() + 1;
console.log(date.getDate() + '-' + mon  + '-' + date.getFullYear()); //returns 29-11-2013
```

Since @RobG mentioned about browser compatibility, here is another approach

```
var date = "2013-11-29 10:12";
var d = date.substring(0, 10).split("-");
console.log(d[2] + "-" + d[1] +"-" + d[0]); //returns 29-11-2013
```

Comment: Do not leave parsing to the Date constructor, it should be done manually. The above will fail in a good number of browsers in use.

Comment: @RobG Thanks, I have add it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the value is always provided as a string, you can adjust the format using:

```
// Reformat 2013-11-29 10:12 to 29-11-2013
function formatDateString(s) {
  var s = s.split(/\D/);
  return s[2] + '-' + s[1] + '-' + s[0];
}
```

Note that this format may be misinterpreted by those who expect dates in month/day/year format.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the string, just get the day/month/year substrings you need with [`substr`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) or [`substring`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp), if you want the a javascript object, you can use [`Date`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the javascript lib [**momentjs**](http://momentjs.com/) to help you handle the time related work.
`moment("2013-11-29 10:12", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm").format("DD-MM-YYYY");`