# Date compare not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I have a simply compare in my *.s file:

```
        var lastSelectedDate = new Date(DateConvert(value));
        var todayDate = new Date($.now());            

        if (lastSelectedDate < todayDate) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
```

When I reach `if`, I have second values:

```
lastSelectedDate = Thu Apr 23 2015 00:00:00 GMT+300
todayDate = Thu Apr 23 2015 15:18:31 GMT+300
```

It is obvious that lastSelectedDate < todayDate

BUT, the thing is, I need to compare those dates without time (condition is for lastSelectedDate to be greater or equal).

Ofcourse It can be done by using .getDay() .getMonth() .getYear() but is there another way to exclude time from it? Without additional libraries?

Comment: Short answer, no not really. You would need to use `setHour`, `setMinute` etc to force the `todayDate` to `00:00:00`

Comment: Something like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698725/comparing-date-part-only-without-comparing-time-in-javascript).

Comment: I thinked about it but there no way to... make in at once? Potentially I will have another similar comparison and that mean, I need to create a function for droping time (DateConvert for example, swap day and month)...

Comment: @OlegsJasjko then it is time to write this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add "setHours" to your code:

```
var todayDate = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)
```

Comment: Em... seems working fine but... adding setHours making from todayDate a bunch of numbers... is this supposed to work that way?

Comment: You can use your DateConvert after that

Comment: It works only with string date, but whatewer. So far looks nice and working :D

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[Date.prototype.setHours()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours)** to set hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds all to 0.

```
 if (lastSelectedDate.setHours(0,0,0,0) < todayDate.setHours(0,0,0,0)) {
```