# DataTables date range filter, not getting the first date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Hi I am using DataTables date range filter. here is the link -> https://datatables.net/extensions/datetime/examples/integration/datatables.html

Below is my code

```
var minDate, maxDate;
 
// Custom filtering function which will search data in column four between two values
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var min = minDate.val();
        var max = maxDate.val();
        var date = new Date( data[9] );
 
        if (
            ( min === null && max === null ) ||
            ( min === null && date <= max ) ||
            ( min <= date   && max === null ) ||
            ( min <= date   && date <= max )
        ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Create date inputs
    minDate = new DateTime($('#min'), {
        format: 'MM-DD-YYYY'
    });
    maxDate = new DateTime($('#max'), {
        format: 'MM-DD-YYYY'
    });

    $('#sales').DataTable({
        aLengthMenu: [
            [25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
            [25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]
        ],
        iDisplayLength: -1,
        scrollX: true
    });
 
    // DataTables initialisation
    var table = $('#sales').DataTable();
 

    // Refilter the table
    $('#min, #max').on('change', function () {
        table.draw();
    });
});
```

When i search from **04-01-2022** to **04-03-2022** . It doesnt show me the record of **04-01-2022**
[image]

But when i enter **03-31-2022** to **04-02-2022** it showing me the record of **04-01-2022**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're setting `MinDate` and `MaxDate` once, on `document.ready`, but not after the user enters dates.

I've moved the code that sets `MinDate` and `MaxDate` into your search filter.

Another potential problem is that you're comparing dates in MM-DD-YYYY format as if they are strings, and this won't work when comparing, say, 03-12-2022 with 05-12-2020. The first date is later from a date perspective, but earlier (first) from a string-comparison perspective. So you should probably be converting dates to YYYY-MM-DD format, which works for string comparison.

I'm not sure about this last part because you have `new Date(...)` (which is standard JS) as well as `new DateTime(...)` (which I don't think is standard JS) so it's not really clear whether you're comparing strings (e.g. `minDate.val()`) or objects (e.g. `new Date( data[9] )`).

```
var minDate, maxDate;
 
// Custom filtering function which will search data in column four between two values
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        // Create date inputs
        minDate = new DateTime($('#min'), {
            format: 'MM-DD-YYYY'
        });
        maxDate = new DateTime($('#max'), {
            format: 'MM-DD-YYYY'
        });

        var min = minDate.val();
        var max = maxDate.val();
        var date = new Date( data[9] );
 
        if (
            ( min === null && max === null ) ||
            ( min === null && date <= max ) ||
            ( min <= date   && max === null ) ||
            ( min <= date   && date <= max )
        ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sales').DataTable({
        aLengthMenu: [
            [25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
            [25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]
        ],
        iDisplayLength: -1,
        scrollX: true
    });
 
    // DataTables initialisation
    var table = $('#sales').DataTable();
 

    // Refilter the table
    $('#min, #max').on('change', function () {
        table.draw();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi sir . You are correct. I have changed the format to YYYY-MM-DD and it worked. But is there a way i can use this format? MM-DD-YYYY?

Comment: @Agent69 See [Compare one date with today using DD-MM-YYYY format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697242/compare-one-date-with-today-using-dd-mm-yyyy-format/41697572). It's not exactly what you're asking for but it's very close and should help with that.