# Google Visualisation Line Chart - Multiple Lines

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, linechart

I have a line chart, h-axis is date, v-axis is double.
I need to display two lines:

```
lineA: [
    [2016-1-1 00:00, 1.1]
    [2016-2-1 00:00, 1.1]
    [2016-3-1 00:00, 1.1]
]
lineB: [
    [2016-1-1 00:00, 2.1]
    [2016-2-1 08:00, 2.1]
    [2016-3-1 00:00, 2.1]
]
```

To display the data on the chart, I need to combine these two lines and pass the result to arrayToDataTable.

```
combine: [
    [2016-1-1 00:00, 1.1, 2.1],
    [2016-2-1 00:00, 1.1, null],
    [2016-2-1 08:00, null, 2.1],
    [2016-3-1 00:00, 1.1, 2.1],
]
```

As a result of the above, I am getting gaps on the lines. How can I solve this issue? Is it possible to pass two individual sets, one for each line? All the examples I have found require them to be merged as the `combine` table.

> I need to keep the nulls when provided as part of line1 and line2
>   table

Comment: You need to consider only the date part. Try check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698725/comparing-date-part-only-without-comparing-time-in-javascript

Comment: Time is important, I can't drop it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the following option to fill in gaps created by `null` values

```
interpolateNulls: true
```

---

**EDIT**

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      [new Date(2016, 0, 1), 1.1, 2.1],
      [new Date(2016, 1, 1), 1.1, null],
      [new Date(2016, 1, 1, 8), null, 2.1],
      [new Date(2016, 2, 1), 1.1, 2.1]
    ], true);

    var options = {
      interpolateNulls: true
    };

    var container = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: I need to keep the nulls when they are provided as part of the line1 and line2 table ... :'(

Comment: interpolateNulls will ignore cases where I have null on purpose (there are cases where line1 / line2 will have null, and there needs to be a gap.

Comment: only option sounds like leaving `interpolateNulls: false` and filling in the blanks manually...

Comment: I was hoping I was missing some knowledge on a different approach of rendering two lines. Thank you for the help