# How to extract only year from date in vue js html and print only that year?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js, vue-component

```
{"status":true,"data":[{"_id":"5addb7cbcd79850454bceb9f","no":12123,"orDate":"2010-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","oldness":"5"},{"_id":"5ae02a26de15e934ac70ee8f","no":11223,"orDate":"2004-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","oldness":"5"},{"_id":"5ae02a26de257934ac70ee8f","no":12311,"orDate":"1994-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","oldness":"5"}]}
```

This is my json response. I need to print only the year from orDate in vue js html.

How can I able to achieve the same.

My html code is

```
<div id="app">
<div v-for="aln in data">
{{aln._id}}
{{aln.no}}
{{aln.orDate}}
</div>
</div>
```

I orDate, I need to print only year from the date. If date is this 2010-01-01T00:00:00.000Z, I need to print 2010 only

My vue js code is

```
app = new Vue({
el: "#iapp",
  data: {
    data:[],
  },
mounted: function() {
 var vm = this;
         $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:4000/get/l/",
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(e) {
            if (e.status == 1) { 
             vm.data = e.data;
             console.log(vm.data);
            }           
            },
        });
},
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've a well-formed date string, you can initialize a date object from the string and call `getFullYear()` on it:

```js
var date = new Date("2010-01-01T00:00:00.000Z");
console.log(date.getUTCFullYear());
```

You can try creating a year key like this in the collection, and use the key in the template:

```
success: function(e) {
  if (e.status == 1) { 
    vm.data = e.data;
    vm.data.forEach(item => {
      var date = new Date(item.orDate);
      item.year = date.getUTCFullYear();
    });
    ...
}
```

In your template, instead of `orDate`, show `year` instead.

```
{{aln.year}}
```

---

**Edit 1:**

As @bbsimonbb pointed out the problem with `getFullYear()`, I've updated my code to use `getUTCFullYear()` instead.

Comment: **[BEWARE THE TIMEZONE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38050824/1585345)**. `getFullYear()` will "helpfully" infer the local timezone. Anywhere West of London, it won't be 2010 yet, and you should see 2009?

Comment: @bbsimonbb -- Thank you. I've updated my code to address this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have 2 choice:

1. `"2010-01-01T00:00:00.000Z".slice(0,4)`
2. `new Date("2010-01-01T00:00:00.000Z").getFullYear()`

Answer (score 1):

[**BEWARE THE TIMEZONE**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38050824/1585345). The accepted answer falls into the trap! Set your device timezone to anything minus (west of london) and you'll get 2009.

[image]

By far the safest way to recover a year from an ISO date string is `.substring(0,3)`. If you want to rehydrate your date into a date object, to format it, compare it or do arithmetic, then you need to be super carefull to avoid getting a timezone when serializing/displaying.

[**To do this safely, use** `getUTCFullYear()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getutcfullyear.asp)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply give like this.

```
<div id="app">
<div v-for="aln in data">
{{aln._id}}
{{aln.no}}
{{new Date(aln.orDate).getFullYear()}}
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how to display only 2000-10-01 from that date

Comment: @BegCoder, for that you can use. `{{aln.orDate.toString().slice(0,10)}}`