# How to create a dynamic table in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, html-table, jsx

I'm trying to code a date picker using ReactJS but I don't know how to create a dynamic table that displays the actual month days every time I hit previous or next buttons.

Here's my code:

```js
// Next step I need to add a matrix of weekdays (1..31) and check each month existing days including leap year days
class DatePicker extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.date = new Date();
    this.months = [
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December"
    ];
    this.days = [
      "sunday",
      "monday",
      "tuesday",
      "wednesdey",
      "thursday",
      "friday",
      "saturday"
    ]; // Should add keys for each item
    this.listWeekDays = this.days.map(day => (
      <li key={day}> {day.slice(0, 2)}</li>
    )); // su mo tu we th fr sa
    this.state = {
      month: this.date.getMonth(),
      year: this.date.getFullYear(),
      monthDays: [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10,
        11,
        12,
        13,
        14,
        15,
        16,
        17,
        18,
        19,
        20,
        21,
        22,
        23,
        24,
        25,
        26,
        27,
        28,
        29,
        30,
        31
      ]
    };

    this.month = () => this.getMonth(this.state.month);

    this.year = () => this.getYear(this.state.year);

    // ***************** days of month
    this.monthDays = [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4,
      5,
      6,
      7,
      8,
      9,
      10,
      11,
      12,
      13,
      14,
      15,
      16,
      17,
      18,
      19,
      20,
      21,
      22,
      23,
      24,
      25,
      26,
      27,
      28,
      29,
      30,
      31
    ];

    /* ******************* EventHandling Binding *****************    */
    this.getNext = this.getNext.bind(this);
    this.getPrevious = this.getPrevious.bind(this);
    /* ***********************************************************    */
  }

  getPrevious() {
    if (this.state.month >= 1) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({ month: prevState.month - 1 }));
    } else {
      this.setState(prevState => ({ month: 11 }));
      this.setState(prevState => ({ year: prevState.year - 1 }));
    }
  }

  getNext() {
    if (this.state.month < 11) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({ month: prevState.month + 1 }));
    } else {
      this.setState(prevState => ({ month: 0 }));
      this.setState(prevState => ({ year: prevState.year + 1 }));
    }
  }

  getWeekDays() {
    return <li>{this.listWeekDays}</li>;
  }

  getFirstDay() {
    // console.log(typeof(this.month()));
    //   console.log(typeof(this.year()));
    const year = this.year().toString();
    const month = this.state.month;
    const firstDay = new Date(year, month, "01");
    return firstDay.getDay();
  }

  getMonth(month) {
    switch (month) {
      case 0:
        return this.months[0];
      case 1:
        return this.months[1];
      case 2:
        return this.months[2];
      case 3:
        return this.months[3];
      case 4:
        return this.months[4];
      case 5:
        return this.months[5];
      case 6:
        return this.months[6];
      case 7:
        return this.months[7];
      case 8:
        return this.months[8];
      case 9:
        return this.months[9];
      case 10:
        return this.months[10];
      case 11:
        return this.months[11];
    }
  }

  getYear(year) {
    return year;
  }

  displayDays = (days, month, year, firstDay) => {
    let tr = document.createElement("tr");
    let td;
    let table = document.createElement("table");
    let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    let i = 0;
    let textNode;

    const emptyTds = () => {
      for (let j = 0; j < firstDay; j++) {
        days.unshift("");
      }
      return days;
    };
    const checkMonthDays = () => {
      if (month === 3 || month === 5 || month === 8 || month === 10) {
        days = days.splice(0, 30);
      } else if (month === 1) {
        // Check if leap year or not
        if (year % 4 === 0) {
          if (year % 100 === 0) {
            if (year % 400 === 0) {
              days = days.splice(0, 29);
            } else days = days.splice(0, 28);
          } else days = days.splice(0, 29);
        } else days = days.splice(0, 28);
      }
      return days;
    };
    const displayDaysTable = () => {
      days.forEach(day => {
        i++;
        td = document.createElement("td");
        textNode = document.createTextNode(day);

        td.appendChild(textNode);
        tr.appendChild(td);
        if (i % 7 === 0) {
          tr = document.createElement("tr");
        }
        table.appendChild(tr);
        body.appendChild(table);
      });
    };

    checkMonthDays();
    emptyTds();
    displayDaysTable();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="ympicker-container">
          <div>
            <input
              type="button"
              className="month-button"
              value="<"
              onClick={this.getPrevious}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="monthyear-container">
            {this.month()} {this.year()}
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="button"
              className="month-button"
              value=">"
              onClick={this.getNext}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="week-days-container">
          <ul className="days-ul"> {this.listWeekDays} </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
          {this.getFirstDay()} //this is the first weekday of the month
        </div>
        <div>
          {this.displayDays(
            this.monthDays,
            this.state.month,
            this.state.year,
            this.firstDay
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const DaysTable = () => {
  return <div />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<DatePicker />, app);
```

```css
.ympicker-container {
 display: flex;
 border: 1px solid black;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 background: #DCDCDC;
 width: 250px;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 600;
 padding: 0px 0;
 font-family: arial, sans serif;
}

.month-button {
 border: 0px solid blue;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: blue;
  height: 40px;
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: none;
 padding: 0 15px;
}

.month-button:hover {
  background: #191970;
 color: white;
}

.week-days-container  {
 display: flex;
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-top: 0;
 width: 250px;
 height: 25px;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.days-ul {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
 font-size: 20px;
 flex-grow:1;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

li {
 display:flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
 align-items: center;  /* Center items */
 flex-direction:column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

I have used `createElement` and `appendChild` but it adds new rows and cells to the table each time I hit the previous/next buttons.

How to create a table that updates existing rows/cells rather than creating new ones?

Comment: Have you looked into something like [react-datepicker](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker) that might solve this difficult problem for you?

Comment: No I didn't. Since I am new to coding and particularly to ReactJS, I wanted to make this code as an exercise but I think it's helpful to take a look at this working application because it's not as easy as I thought it would be...

Comment: Append is not a bad option , but you have to empty the table first and then add new rows in order to get updated.

Comment: You should break this task into smaller pieces. For example, make a `Month` component. The end goal is to take a `name` prop or something similar to indicate what month it is and then generate a grid with numbers for the days, with the 1st starting on the correct day of the week. However, doing all that at once is difficult. So take a step back and make a grid with the numbers 1 through 30 and start on Sunday. Once you get that working, then add more functionality a little at a time.

Comment: Note that in React, you can do `let table = <table></table>` instead of using `createElement()`.

Comment: getMonth() is timezone specific. If your dates contain just dates without times, you will often be better using getUTCMonth(). [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38050824/1585345) !

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions:

1. Use JSX syntax for all elements. For example, you can do

   ```
   let table = <table/>;
   ```
2. Similarly you can create `<td>` elements with `map()` instead of `forEach()`:

   ```
   let tds = days.map(day => <td>day</td>);
   ```

   Now you need to split this list of days into the correct groups for each `<tr>`.
3. Reduce `getMonth()` to a single line with a return:

   ```
   return this.months[month];
   ```
4. Create a function named `isLeapYear()` to make this calculation more readable.