# Angular 6 custom validator for comparing current date to selected date is not validating properly and allowing any value to be added

Tags: angular, validation, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, customvalidator

I need to validate a date of birth control of a reactive form, so if a user selected a value from the future, to disable the save button:

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

export function validateDOB(control: AbstractControl)
{

    let currentDateTime = new Date();
    let monthValue = currentDateTime.getMonth()+1;
    let formattedDate = currentDateTime.getFullYear() +'-'+ monthValue +'-'+currentDateTime.getDay();

    let controlValue = control.value;
    let monthOfControlValue = controlValue.getMonth()+1;
    let FinalControlValue = controlValue.getFullYear()+'-'+monthOfControlValue+'-'+controlValue.getDay;
    console.log(FinalControlValue)
    if(formattedDate<control.value)
    {
        return {response: true};
    }
    return null;
}
```

Explanation:

I am working with angular material date picker, so the date will be displayed like the following:

> Mon Oct 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)

the first 3 line are getting the current date and transforming it to `YYYY-mm-dd` format:

```
let currentDateTime = new Date();
let monthValue = currentDateTime.getMonth()+1;
let formattedDate = currentDateTime.getFullYear() +'-'+ 
              monthValue +'-'+currentDateTime.getDay();
```

The last 3 lines are converting the date selected by the user:

```
let monthOfControlValue = controlValue.getMonth()+1;
let FinalControlValue = controlValue.getFullYear()+'-'+monthOfControlValue+'-'+controlValue.getDay;
console.log(FinalControlValue )
```

At the user side, any date, whether it was less than or greater than, the validation will not work.

I tried to make the comparison without converting into `YYYY-mm-dd`, but it didn't/wouldn't work.

I changed the script by changing the value of the control into a new date:

```
let controlValue = new Date(control.value);
```

And the script is now like:

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

export function validateDOB(control: AbstractControl)
{

    let currentDateTime = new Date();
    let monthValue = currentDateTime.getMonth()+1;
    let formattedDate = currentDateTime.getFullYear() +'-'+ monthValue +'-'+currentDateTime.getDay();
    console.log(formattedDate)
    let controlValue = new Date(control.value);
    let monthOfControlValue = controlValue.getMonth()+1;
    let FinalControlValue = controlValue.getFullYear()+'-'+monthOfControlValue+'-'+controlValue.getDay();
    console.log(FinalControlValue)
    if(formattedDate<control.value)
    {
        return {response: true};
    }
    return null;
}
```

And still not working.

Comment: Did you try to format your dates with a formatter like DatePipe ?

Comment: How to use inside typescript function

Comment: You have to import it, construct it and then use the transform method like that `dateTransformed = this.datePipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');`

Comment: can I construct it inside an exported function ?

Comment: Yes, in the constructor

Comment: An exported function can have a constructor ? @veben

Comment: @droidnation why do you allow user to select the future date?

Comment: I can't manage the date picker of angular material to display past dates. I searched for it but couldn't find any help. Anyway @PrashantPimpale I answered my own question, please check it. It works for me.

Comment: Good, but you could easily disable the today's date and future dates in the DatePicker so that part of writing the explicit code will be eliminated

Comment: If you are unable to do the same then let me know

Comment: Yes I am unable to do it. Can you tell me how to do it @PrashantPimpale ?

Comment: html code please

Comment: Here is stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ftem5m

Comment: Post it as an answer please so I can vote it up.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of writing custom Validate function to disable the dates, I would use `MAX` property of date picker to disable the Today's Date and Future dates from being selected.

The HTML Code:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input matInput [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

And in TS file:

```
 minDate = new Date(1900, 0, 1);
 maxDate =  new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1))
```

Here is [StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ftem5m)

[Reference Link](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview)

Answer (score 1):

could you try this?

```
if(currentDateTime <controlValue )
```

with

```
let controlValue = new Date(control.value);
```

formattedDate is a string in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the answer is based on the help provided by @lesiano. But the main problem was that the comparing is including the time. And as mentioned in [this old stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698725/comparing-date-part-only-without-comparing-time-in-javascript?answertab=active#tab-top), we need to set the time of the date into `0's`, so the comparison take place:

```
date1.setHours(0,0,0,0)
```

The working custom validator is:

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

export function validateDOB(control: AbstractControl)
{

    let currentDateTime = new Date();
    currentDateTime.setHours(0,0,0,0);

    let controlValue = new Date(control.value);
    controlValue.setHours(0,0,0,0);

    //console.log(currentDateTime+'-'+controlValue)

    if(currentDateTime<control.value)
    {
        return {response: true};
    }
    return null;
}
```