# Convert string to Date without considering timezone - Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, momentjs

I'm getting a date as a string, in the following format (for example):

```
"11/10/2015 10:00:00"
```

This is UTC time.

When I create Date from this string, it consider it as local time:

```
let time = "11/10/2015 10:00:00";
let date = new Date(time); 
console.log(date);
```

it prints:

```
"Tue Nov 10 2015 10:00:00 GMT+0200"
```

(instead of considering it as UTC: "Tue Nov 10 2015 10:00:00")

I also tried moment.js for that.

is there a good way to make Date() consider the string a UTC, without adding "Z"/"UTC"/"+000" in the end of the string?

Comment: You can use `moment.utc("11/10/2015 10:00:00", "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss")`, do you want to a native JavaScript solution?

Comment: @VincenzoC `Date.UTC()` does the same thing natively

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in `Date.UTC()` function to do this. Here's a little function that will take the format you gave in your original post and converts it to a UTC date string

```js
let time = "11/10/2015 10:00:00";

function getUTCDate(dateString) {
  // dateString format will be "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss"
  var [date, time] = dateString.split(" ");
  var [month, day, year] = date.split("/");
  var [hours, minutes, seconds] = time.split(":");
  // month is 0 indexed in Date operations, subtract 1 when converting string to Date object
  return new Date(Date.UTC(year, month - 1, day, hours, minutes, seconds)).toUTCString();
}

console.log(getUTCDate(time));
```

Comment: You're assuming month/day/year format, but given the OP was posted at 2018-10-10 15:36:59Z, it's more likely to be the much more common day/month/year format. ;-)

Comment: @RobG OP wants "Nov 10th 2015" to spit out, correct? With an input of `"11/10/2015"` that's exactly what you'll get. For that reason, I assumed it was "month/day/year", unless I'm missing something?

Comment: The OP says "*it prints*", not "*I want*". You might be correct, but it's not certain.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I meant that I expected:"Tue Nov 10 2015 10:00:00" (without "+0200")

Answer (score 2):

Your date is parsed by the date constructor, in MM/DD/YYYY format, applying the local timezone offset (so the output represents local midnight at the start of the day in question). If your date really is MM/DD/YYYY, all you need to do is subtract the timezone offset and you'll have the UTC date...

```js
var myDate = new Date("11/10/2015 10:00:00");
myDate = new Date( myDate.getTime() - (myDate.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000));
console.log(myDate.toLocaleString([],{timeZone:'UTC'}))
```

[Here's everything I know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38050824/1585345) about managing timezone when serializing and deserializing dates. All the timezone handling is static! JS dates have no intrinsic timezone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) for this but you will have to parse your string and put every part of it as args by yourself as it can't parse such string. Also you could use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to parse it: [Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

Also, seems like `new Date("11/10/2015 10:00:00 GMT")` parses date as a GMT and only after that converts it to PC local time

Comment: "*Also, seems like…*" Worth noting that "11/10/2015 10:00:00 GMT" is not a format supported by EMCA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent.  It's also ambiguous, most people will recognise it as 11 October, but parsers may well treat it as 10 November.

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer is to append a "Z" at the end without changing the variable:

```
let time = "11/10/2015 10:00:00";  
let date = new Date(time + "Z");  
console.log(date);
```