# Moment.js resolve timezone offset

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm working in an Angular 6 front end and receive from another system time stamps which have no time zones (C# backend, DateTime). I suspect that javascript is automatically adding the local time zone to Date objects.

Example:

Receiving from backend: `2018-10-15T07:53:00.000Z`

When console logging: `console.log(timestamp) // Mon Oct 15 2018 09:53:00 GMT+0200`

I am using moment.js and already tried `moment.utc()` and `moment(DATE).utc()`. But it still adds the local time zone especially because I have to re-transform my moment objects back to the type `Date` with `.toDate()`.

How can I resolve the time zone difference and get back a utc date to work with or the same structure as received?

Answer (score 1):

try to format use as per desired.

```js
let str = '2018-10-15T07:53:00.000Z';
let moment = moment(str).utcOffset(str)
console.log(moment.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'))
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Second Snippet (to use the date object from string)

```js
let str = '2018-10-15T07:53:00.000Z';
let moment = moment(str).utcOffset(str);
console.log(moment.toDate())
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem is, `.format()` returns a string which is correctly formatted indeed, but I need a Date object for further work (e.g. date comparison).

Comment: @knnhcn there is a moment().toDate();

Comment: Indeed, but in the docs it reads: `As Javascript Date: To get a copy of the native Date object that Moment.js wraps`. So it's basically only a wrapper and you get the same result as native js `.toDate()`. [link](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/)

Answer (score 1):

Your input is UTC and will be parsed just fine. Javascript Dates have no notion of timezone! The local timezone is applied by the static methods for serializing (`Date.toString()`, `Date.toDateString()` etc.) (Console.log(Date) uses `Date.toString()`.)

Use `Date.toLocaleString([],{timeZone:"UTC"})`. Forcing UTC, you will see in the output the same time as the input. Much more details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38050824/1585345) :-)

Here it is working:

```js
console.log(new Date('2018-10-15T07:53:00.000Z').toLocaleString([],{timeZone:'UTC'}))
```