# Need to set Time value 00:00:00 in DatePicker date value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, time, datepicker

In my react native app, I have used DatePicker using which I get Date value like this "**2019-03-19T18:30:00.000Z**". Here in this case I need to set the time value to '**0**'. So, the expected output would look like "**2019-03-19T00:00:00.000Z**". Please help me resolve this issue.!

Thanks in advance.!

```
<Item>  
    <DatePicker
        ref='datepicker'
        defaultDate={new Date(2019, 2, 18)}
        minimumDate={new Date(2010, 1, 1)}
        maximumDate={new Date(2030, 12, 31)}
        locale={"en"}
        timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={undefined}
        modalTransparent={false}
        animationType={"fade"}
        androidMode={"default"}
        placeHolderText="Select Date"
        textStyle={{ color: "green" }}
        placeHolderTextStyle={{ color: "#d3d3d3" }}
        onDateChange={this.setDate}
        disabled={false}
    />
</Item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is how to create a midnight UTC date object representing the user's local date. new Date() used alone gives you local midnight. Try instead...

```
new Date(Date.UTC(2019, 2, 18));
```

More useful info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698725/comparing-date-part-only-without-comparing-time-in-javascript/38050824#38050824) !