# How to tell if two dates are equal while ignoring time?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to compare two dates to see if they are the same, while ignoring Time as well.

I've tried using the .setHours(0,0,0,0) method to set the time to something neutral, but then I can't use the .getTime() method due to this error.. 
`Property 'getTime' does not exist on type 'number'`

I've also researched that I shouldn't use ===, but I can't overcome the getTime problem first.

```
if (this.datelist.filter(x => new Date (x.sentDate).setHours(0,0,0,0).getTime() === this.searchQuery.getTime()).length == 0) {
    console.log("No matches");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing date part only without comparing time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698725/comparing-date-part-only-without-comparing-time-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Date#setHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) method already returns the time in a millisecond so you cant use [`Date#getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method on a [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

Since [`Date#setHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) method already returns the time you can simply ignore the [`Date#getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method and compare with the returned value.

```
if (this.datelist.filter(x => new Date(x.sentDate).setHours(0,0,0,0) === this.searchQuery.getTime()).length == 0) {
    console.log("No matches");
}
```

---

For this purpose, you can use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method instead of [`Array#fileter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```
if (this.datelist.every(x => new Date(x.sentDate).setHours(0,0,0,0) !== this.searchQuery.getTime())) {
    console.log("No matches");
}
```

Comment: Ugh, knew I was missing something simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend **Moment.js** for these kind of date operations. It is so much easier with Moment.js

```
moment('2019-04-25').isSame('2019-04-25'); // true
```

There are format methods available to covert the date to YYYY-MM-DD before comparing.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the concatenation of methods.

When you have `thing.methodA().methodB()`, `methodB` will work with whatever returns from `methodA`, and in this case, setHours returns a time BUT in miliseconds from the baseDate, which is a number, and has no `getTime()` method.

Your solution is using the setHours in both objects after copying them, that'd be:

```
if (this.datelist.filter(x => new Date (x.sentDate).setHours(0,0,0,0) === this.searchQuery.setHours(0,0,0,0)).length === 0) {
    console.log("nope!");
}
```

also note that '===' should be used in all cases always except when checking empty values (you use `val == null`).

cheers!