# Angular Material Datepicker: How to filter so that only dates in an array are allowed?

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I have an array of dates returned from an API. For example, I might have an array entitled `validDates` that has all of the Mondays in September as their values. I would like to use the Material [Datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) filter to only allow date values in the array to be selected.

### Example Date Array

```
validDates = [
    Mon Sep 02 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time),
    Mon Sep 09 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time),
    Mon Sep 16 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time),
    Mon Sep 23 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time),
    Mon Sep 30 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
]
```

### Datepicker Filter (not working)

```
myFilter = ( d: Date ): boolean => {
    let dateOpen: boolean;
    for ( let x = 0; x < this.validDates.length; x++ ) {
      dateOpen = d.toString() === this.validDates[ x ].toString();
    }
    return dateOpen;
  }
```

The issue is it only returns the last date (Mon Sep 30 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)) as `true` so that only the 30th becomes selectable. I want each of the dates in the array to be selectable.

How can I return `true` for each value in the array?

Comment: where is myFilter used?

Comment: myFilter is used in the component html view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only allow dates within an array, the `myFilter` method may be defined as follows.

```
myFilter = (d: Date): boolean => {
  // Only allow dates in `validDates`.
  return this.validDates.findIndex( (valid_date) => d.getTime() === valid_date.getTime()) > -1
}
```

See [**Stackblitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so58244231-date-filter?file=app/datepicker-filter-example.ts)

To ignore the time component of the `Date`, see:
[**Comparing date part only without comparing time in JavaScript**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2698725/1164465)

Comment: Worked perfectly and an elegant response. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found correct solution:

```js
// The array of days of week to be available
const arr = [0, 3, 6];
this.expressSenderDate = (d: Date): boolean => {
    const day = d.getDay();
    // tslint:disable-next-line:align
    return arr.indexOf(day) !== -1;
};
```