# How to find string format type of date is passed in Date object?

Tags: javascript

I have two date object like *new Date(2019, 11, 1)* and *new Date("2019-12-01")*. 
The obtained Date object values are different.

[image]

How can I get the same Date object for both values by any possible workarounds? I have tried by adding new Date().getTimezoneOffset(), but it did not work proper if I have *new Date(2019, 11, 1, 4)*

Comment: You can add time to your date string: `new Date("2019-12-01 00:00:00")`

Comment: Any workaround? So how about simply `new Date("2019-12-01 00:00:00")` and `new Date(2019, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0)`? ;)

Comment: My case is I am giving the date in either new Date(2019, 11, 1) or new Date("2019-12-01") this format only. So, I can't change the initial values.

Comment: I would say the best option is to parse the string before passing it to the new date object. For example: const parsedDate = "2019-12-01".split("-"); And then initialize the date as follows: new Date(parsedDate[0], parsedDate[1]-1, parsedDate[2]); Or even better, use [Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) to initialize all your dates [new Date(Date.UTC(2019, 10, 9)].

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, javascript is assuming the local timezone. For representing just-a-date, this is very problematic. Use instead `Date.UTC(2019,11,1)`

In the second example, javascript is assuming UTC which is what you want.

Much more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698725/comparing-date-part-only-without-comparing-time-in-javascript/38050824#38050824).