# How to compare date without the time in html

Tags: html, angular

I would like to compare two dates without times (only day, month and year) in html. Is this possible?

I' written code like this:

```
<span class="date" *ngIf="(i == 0) || (application.date != applications[i-1].date)">{{application.date | date: 'EEEE, dd-MM-yyyy' }}</span>
```

But the problem is: application.date look like: "2020-07-01T13:48:09.3304012+02:00"

Comment: That's not HTML. The code in the `*ngIf` is JavaScript, and it appears you're using Angular - an important piece of information you'll want to include in questions. Also, is `application.date` a `Date` object or actually a string?

Comment: `application.date` is a Date not a string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing date part only without comparing time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698725/comparing-date-part-only-without-comparing-time-in-javascript)