# How to get date difference in JS in days (regardless of hour difference)

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Sorry if the question is a duplicate but I couldn't find anything on my case here.
I got a function `getDaysDiff` where I pass two arguments `(startDate, endDate)` which are date strings, and expect to get the difference between two dates in days but with some details.
Like so:

1. If I pass `'2021-07-19T23:59:59'` and `'2021-07-20T00:00:01'` I want to get **1 day** as a return value because the dates are different even though the number of hours is less than 24
2. Same for the case where the two dates are close but the number of  hours is more than 24, like `'2021-07-19T00:00:01'` and `'2021-07-20T23:59:59'`, in this case, I still want to get **1 day**
3. And finally it should work as well with the adjacent dates from different months, like `'2021-07-30T23:59:59'` and `'2021-08-01T00:00:01'` should return **1 day** as well.

I tried to apply the following function but thanks to `Math.round/floor/ceil` it breaks anyways for one of the cases above.

```js
function getDaysDiff(start, end) {
  const date1 = new Date(start);
  const date2 = new Date(end);

  const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

  const diffInTime = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();

  const diffInDays = Math.ceil(diffInTime / oneDay);

  return diffInDays;
}

console.log(getDaysDiff('2021-07-19T23:59:59', '2021-07-20T00:00:01'));
console.log(getDaysDiff('2021-07-19T00:00:01', '2021-07-20T23:59:59'));
console.log(getDaysDiff('2021-07-31T23:59:59', '2021-08-01T00:00:01'));
```

Is there a consice way to get this difference?

Comment: In other words, you want the day of month difference, regardless of the time?

Comment: Dont work with time. Just work with the date right?

Comment: That's correct @ChrisG

Comment: using getDate() instead of getTime() fails on the last condition, wrapping month.

Comment: Before subtracting, call `setHours(0)` on start and end, same for minutes and seconds: https://jsfiddle.net/tLfpv50b/

Comment: Why is the expected difference between  `'2021-07-30T23:59:59'` and `'2021-08-01T00:00:01'` one day? That are not adjacent dates

Comment: @jabaa 2, because July has actually 31 days. Probably just a mistake by OP.

Comment: @jabaa , sorry a typo

Comment: lol, throwing that use case.

Comment: @chrisG you should post the answer. i can confirm date1.setHours(0,0,0)
date2.setHours(0,0,0) works.

Comment: @ChrisG, that works great, post it as an answer please

Comment: I would, it's a dupe though: [Comparing date part only without comparing time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698725/comparing-date-part-only-without-comparing-time-in-javascript)

Comment: Given the format of the timestamps, you can do: `let daysDiff = Math.round((new Date(dateA).setHours(0,0,0,0) - new Date(dateB).setHours(0,0,0,0)) / 8.64e7)`. Rounding is required as if the dates go over a daylight saving boundary, the result will not be an exact multiple of ms in a day.