# How to compare two dates without hours in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two dates `date` and `meeting.date` coming from two APIs. I want to check, if the dates are equal.

```js
// date = "28.02.2022";
// meeting.date = "2022-02-08 14:30:00";

const firstDate = new Date(`${date.split(".").reverse().join("-")}`);
const secondDate = new Date(`${meeting.date.split(" ")[0]}`)

firstDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
secondDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);

console.log(firstDate, secondDate, firstDate === secondDate);
```

This logs me

```
[Log] Mon Feb 28 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)  – Mon Feb 28 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)  – false
```

I expect that to be true?
I found the solution, setting the hours to zero here on stackoverflow, but I'd say, that this is gratuitous, as I don't pass the time the Date. Anyhow, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698725/comparing-date-part-only-without-comparing-time-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing date part only without comparing time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698725/comparing-date-part-only-without-comparing-time-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing here is comparing two different instances (two different references) of `Date` object, which lead to an unexpected result

You could try to compare the millisecond of these by using [`getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

```js
const date = "28.02.2022";
const meeting = { date: "2022-02-28 14:30:00" }

const firstDate = new Date(`${date.split(".").reverse().join("-")}`);
const secondDate = new Date(`${meeting.date.split(" ")[0]}`)

firstDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
secondDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);

console.log(firstDate, secondDate, firstDate.getTime() === secondDate.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the Date objects themselves - and they will never be equal unless it is the same "object" pointed to by 2 different variables, e.g.

```js
const dateOne = dateTwo = new Date();
```

You must either compare the date parts as Strings, e.g.

```js
console.log(
  firstDate,
  secondDate,
  firstDate.toISOString().substr(0, 10) === secondDate.toISOString().substr(0, 10)
);
```

or compare the dates as Numbers (in milliseconds) which is the recommended way:

```js
console.log(
  firstDate,
  secondDate,
  firstDate.getTime() === secondDate.getTime()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.getTime()` method to convert both of the dates to the number of milliseconds since the [ECMAScript epoch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#the_ecmascript_epoch_and_timestamps) and then compare them.

```js
firstDate.setHours(0,0,0,0).getTime();
secondDate.setHours(0,0,0,0).getTime();
console.log(firstDate, secondDate, firstDate === secondDate);
```