# Wrong time in maxDate

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

Hello I am using `maxDate` in `datetimepicker` like this:

```
const today = new Date()
$('#recordtime').datetimepicker({
   sideBySide: true,
   locale: 'bg',
   format: 'DD/MM/YYYY  HH:mm:ss',
   maxDate: today
});
```

But the problem is that I can pick till 8:00:00 - today
[image]

Why is That? Do I need to set some  local time settings in the script to restrict to 00:00:00?

The js that I use is:
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37

Comment: What is `datetimepicker`? What does the documentation of that plugin say about the `maxDate` property? Did you try anything yourself to solve this (like setting the minutes and hours to zero)?

Comment: @Andreas I cant find any info about this problem...

Comment: That doesn't answer any of my questions...

Comment: @Andreas this is `bootstrap-datepicker` plugin

Comment: @Rederdex `const today = new Date()` is the first line of OPs code...

Comment: @Rederdex now here is 10:55. And the 8:00:00 restriction is the same

Comment: For boostrap-datepicker, use `endDate` with `"today"` (a string) or `"0d"` as in the example.  https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#enddate

Comment: The linked documentation has only the `format` option of your config. Either its not the bootstrap datepicker, or your config is wrong.

Comment: Also, if "maxdate" is today, then today is allowed

Comment: This feels like a time zone issue. Are you, by any chance, in a GMT +/- 8 timezone?

Comment: As noted by @Andreas above, https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ is a date picker, it doesn't include *time* - so it's not the "datetimepicker" that you're using.  Please let us know the actual date+time picker.

Comment: If you don't want "today" then set the max date to "yesterday".  Or, if it has a time, then yesterday 23:59 - or today 00:00 - `new Date()` in javascript includes the current time.  The datepicker/datetimepicker *should* have a concept of "maxDate today" without needing to pass in  a date object - if you told us the correct plugin, we could possibly help you find it.

Comment: Sorry the js that I use is made by: bootstrap-datetimejs
 https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker
 Copyright (c) 2015 Jonathan Peterson

Comment: `new Date()` includes time, so you're setting max to "now" rather than "beginning of today".  It's unclear from "*But the problem is that I can pick till 8:00:00 - today*" if you're expecting to be able to select any time today or not today at all.   Seems the easiest solution is to set hours/minutes to zero on your `today` variable:  `today.setHours(0,0,0,0)` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6202196/2181514 and related answers regarding potential timezone issues - probably not an issue for a datetimepicker.

Comment: @freedomn-m you are right, still the main problem now I see that the time is 09:00:00, instead of 08. I think now that timezone is the problem like phuzi says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set the time to `today.setHours(23,59,59,0)` like @freedomn-m said and add `timeZone` as @phuzi wrote.

```
const today = new Date()
today.setHours(23,59,59,0)
$('#recordtime').datetimepicker({
locale: 'bg',
format: 'DD/MM/YYYY  HH:mm:ss',
timeZone: 'Europe/Sofia',
maxDate: today
});
```

Thanks for the help in the comments and sorry for the wrong info that I wrote for the used js script...