# Display Current Date on JSF Page

Tags: jsf-2

Is it possible to display the current date (today's) in JSF without using a backing bean?

I have the following code snippet , but it didn't work out.

```
<div class="leftSide">Today's date #{currentDate}</div>
```

or

```
<f:facet name="header">  
<h:outputText value="Today's date" />  
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#currentDate">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" type="date" />
</h:outputText>
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You could register an instance of `java.util.Date` as a request scoped bean in `faces-config.xml`.

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>currentDate</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>java.util.Date</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

This way it's available as `#{currentDate}` without the need for a custom backing bean class.

---

**Update**: the JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has such a bean [already registered](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/managedbeans/now) as `#{now}`. So if you happen to use OmniFaces already, you can just make use of it directly.

```
<h:outputText value="#{now}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" type="date" />
</h:outputText>
```

Answer (score 33):

In JSF you could use the implicit EL object `session` that provides access to the current [HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html). The `HttpSession#getLastAccessedTime` time ...

> ... returns the last time the client sent a request associated with this
>   session, as the number of milliseconds since midnight January 1, 1970
>   GMT, and marked by the time the container received the request.

So you could use the following code snippet in your facelet:

```
<h:outputText value="#{session.lastAccessedTime}">
      <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" type="date" />
</h:outputText>
```

This will be server time and may differ from client time with respect to different time zones.

But you could also use a javascript solution, as discussed here:

[How do I get the current date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Is `session` guaranteed to exist (be non-null) in every request?

Comment: Actually, lastAccessTime yields the time of the previous request. That may be a couple of minutes off the current time.

Answer (score 8):

Or you could do it using Omnifaces. I'm surprised BalusC hasn't told you about this solution (I think he's a great Omnifaces contributor). Maybe it's because using Omnifaces just to display a simple date in a page might be an overkill to some.

Anyway, if your project already uses [Omnifaces](http://omnifaces.org), there are 2 managed beans exposed by default and one in particular that you may find handy. As per the [tag documentation](http://omnifaces.org/docs/vdldoc/current/) specifies, once Omnifaces is added to your project, you can use the `#{now}` managed bean.

For instance, to set a Primefaces calendar's max date, I just wrote the following :

```
    <p:calendar id="myCalendar" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" 
                value="#{mybean.myDate}" maxdate="#{now}"/>
```

I guess the `#{now}` managed bean can be used in many more situations, and probably yours as well.

If your project does not use Omnifaces yet, I suggest you look at their spec and see how helpful it could be for you.
For instance, I'm using their `validateOrder` tag to make sure two dates are properly ordered.

Comment: OmniFaces didn't exist yet at the moment I posted the answer :)

Comment: Mystery solved ! ;) ... I didn't know Omnifaces was that young. That's some great work anyway !

Comment: `I think he's a great Omnifaces contributor`. BalusC authored OmniFaces. It's his baby.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the  tag which PrimeFaces provide.

```
<p:clock pattern="HH:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy"/>
```