# How to get current year in jsf without using backend bean

Tags: jsf

I want to update the copyright year dynamically to current year in jsf. where i should have to do it by using jsf tag and not using the support of backend bean. Please help me fix this problem.

Comment: Here is the answer to your question : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9177715/354831

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie if the question is a dup, provide a close vote better ;-)