# Getting current date and time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, time, concatenation

I have a script that prints the current date and time in JavaScript, but the `DATE` is always wrong. Here is the code:

```
var currentdate = new Date();
var datetime = "Last Sync: " + currentdate.getDay() + "/" + currentdate.getMonth() 
+ "/" + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ " 
+ currentdate.getHours() + ":" 
+ currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentdate.getSeconds();
```

It should print `18/04/2012 15:07:33` and prints `3/3/2012 15:07:33`

Comment: In general, you should endeavor to read the documentation of the APIs you are using.  Here is some documentation for Javascript Date objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date.  Everything you need to know to fix your problem can been found there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get current date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript)

Comment: I think JavaScript will get the current date and time from System. Hence, set the current date and time in your Computer.

Comment: It was wednesday (3, zero based starting at sunday), month of index 3 (zero based) of 2012

Comment: People always complain about certain questions but there are very few questions on SO that couldn't be answered by reading documentation. I love this site because it has concise answers and examples of how to do what I'm trying to do, exactly like this question does.

Comment: when people google they get here instead of the api doc, is it so bad to share the knowledge without making people feed bad ?

Answer (score 777, accepted):

`.getMonth()` returns a zero-based number so to get the correct month you need to add 1, so calling `.getMonth()` in may will return `4` and not `5`.

So in your code we can use `currentdate.getMonth()+1` to output the correct value. In addition:

- `.getDate()` returns the day of the month **<- this is the one you want**
- `.getDay()` is a separate method of the `Date` object which will return an integer representing the current day of the week (0-6) `0 == Sunday` etc

so your code should look like this:

```
var currentdate = new Date(); 
var datetime = "Last Sync: " + currentdate.getDate() + "/"
                + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
                + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
                + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
                + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
                + currentdate.getSeconds();
```

---

> JavaScript Date instances inherit from Date.prototype. You can modify the constructor's prototype object to affect properties and methods inherited by JavaScript Date instances

You can make use of the `Date` prototype object to create a new method which will return today's date and time. These new methods or properties will be inherited by all instances of the `Date` object thus making it especially useful if you need to re-use this functionality.

```
// For todays date;
Date.prototype.today = function () { 
    return ((this.getDate() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getDate() +"/"+(((this.getMonth()+1) < 10)?"0":"") + (this.getMonth()+1) +"/"+ this.getFullYear();
}

// For the time now
Date.prototype.timeNow = function () {
     return ((this.getHours() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getHours() +":"+ ((this.getMinutes() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getMinutes() +":"+ ((this.getSeconds() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getSeconds();
}
```

You can then simply retrieve the date and time by doing the following:

```
var newDate = new Date();
var datetime = "LastSync: " + newDate.today() + " @ " + newDate.timeNow();
```

Or call the method inline so it would simply be -

```
var datetime = "LastSync: " + new Date().today() + " @ " + new Date().timeNow();
```

Comment: Small change for 12 hour days & AM/PM

`Date.prototype.timeNow = function(){
    return ((this.getHours() < 10)?"0":"") + ((this.getHours()>12)?(this.getHours()-12):this.getHours()) +":"+ ((this.getMinutes() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getMinutes() +":"+ ((this.getSeconds() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getSeconds() + ((this.getHours()>12)?('PM'):'AM');
};`

Comment: @RobertSpeer nice suggestion. I have written a more usable method of the date object since last updating this post which I call `now()` which takes a boolean parameter to determine whether to return just the date or both date and time, and also a second paramater which specifies the format which the date should be returned in i.e dd/mm/yyyy etc.

Comment: Notice that times like 00:04:02 will be rendered like 0:4:2 in the first suggestion, which is not what was asked for. To fix this, one could add the ternary operators of the second suggestion:

`(date.getHours() < 10 ? "0" : "") + date.getHours() + ":" +
(date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" : "") + date.getMinutes() + ":" +
(date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" : "") + date.getSeconds();`

Comment: Perhaps a bit nitty-gritty; but shouldn't the timestamp be stored in a temporary object to avoid the current date/time changing during the retrieval / print methods?

Comment: Update: `('0' + this.getDate()).slice(-2)` seems like shorter than `(this.getDate() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getDate()`

Comment: Note that the source to why it starts at 0 makes no logical sense. It postulates that checking if an index is within bounds you'd instead of `0 ≤ index < N` do `1 ≤ index < N+1` which means an extra addition. This logic is flawed since you could also do `0 < index ≤ N` which has an negligible amount of impact.

Comment: @MarkWalters - " I have written a more usable method of the date object since last updating this post which I call now() which takes a boolean parameter...". I love your answer here (above)... It'd be great if you could update your answer adding that "now()" code. Or, have you put that code in another post/answer?

Comment: ".getMonth() returns a zero-based number so to get the correct month you need to add 1" - Thanks for this

Answer (score 517):

To get time and date you should use

```
    new Date().toLocaleString();

>> "09/08/2014, 2:35:56 AM"
```

To get only the date you should use

```
    new Date().toLocaleDateString();

>> "09/08/2014"
```

To get only the time you should use

```
    new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

>> "2:35:56 AM"
```

Or if you just want the time in the format `hh:mm` without AM/PM for US English

```
    new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour12: false, 
                                             hour: "numeric", 
                                             minute: "numeric"});
>> "02:35"
```

or for British English

```
    new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-GB', { hour: "numeric", 
                                             minute: "numeric"});

>> "02:35"
```

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString).

Comment: this works in most browsers, but you can check the compatibility [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString#Browser_Compatibility)

Comment: too bad you can't get micro/milliseconds easily with this

Comment: Plus one. I was looking for a way to keep both digits. I was using `getHours()` and `getMinutes()` before, but then you don't get the format, 01, only 1.

Comment: Avoid using toLocaleTimeString & similar localemethods because everytime they are  called, JS engine has to perform a search in a big database of localization strings, which is potentially inefficient. When the method is called many times with the same arguments, it is better to create a Intl.DateTimeFormat object and use its format() method

Answer (score 90):

For true mysql style output use this function below:  `2023-11-28 15:33:12`

- If you click the 'Run code snippet' button below
- It will show you an simple realtime digital clock example
- The demo will appear below the code snippet.

```js
function getDateTime() {
        var now     = new Date(); 
        var year    = now.getFullYear();
        var month   = now.getMonth()+1; 
        var day     = now.getDate();
        var hour    = now.getHours();
        var minute  = now.getMinutes();
        var second  = now.getSeconds(); 
        if(month.toString().length == 1) {
             month = '0'+month;
        }
        if(day.toString().length == 1) {
             day = '0'+day;
        }   
        if(hour.toString().length == 1) {
             hour = '0'+hour;
        }
        if(minute.toString().length == 1) {
             minute = '0'+minute;
        }
        if(second.toString().length == 1) {
             second = '0'+second;
        }   
        var dateTime = year+'-'+month+'-'+day+' '+hour+':'+minute+':'+second;   
         return dateTime;
    }

    // example usage: realtime clock
    setInterval(function(){
        currentTime = getDateTime();
        document.getElementById("digital-clock").innerHTML = currentTime;
    }, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="digital-clock"></div>
```

Comment: Cleanest answer I see ever. :)

Answer (score 36):

Just use:

```
var d = new Date();
document.write(d.toLocaleString());
document.write("<br>");
```

Comment: Also something similar: toUTCString(). Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString, where the is a list of similar functions on side bar of it.

Answer (score 35):

## Short

I develop [Steve answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28255885/860099) to get exactly what OP need

```
new Date().toLocaleString().replace(',','')
```

```js
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString().replace(',',''));
```

Answer (score 17):

```
var currentdate = new Date();

    var datetime = "Last Sync: " + currentdate.getDate() + "/"+(currentdate.getMonth()+1) 
    + "/" + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ " 
    + currentdate.getHours() + ":" 
    + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentdate.getSeconds();
```

Change `.getDay()` method to `.GetDate()` and add one to month, because it counts months from 0.

Answer (score 9):

This should do the trick:

```
function dateToString(date) {
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = date.getDate();
    var dateOfString = (("" + day).length < 2 ? "0" : "") + day + "/";
    dateOfString += (("" + month).length < 2 ? "0" : "") + month + "/";
    dateOfString += date.getFullYear();
    return dateOfString;
}

var currentdate = new Date();
var datetime = "Last Sync: ";
datetime += dateToString(currentdate );
datetime += + currentdate.getHours() + ":"
            + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":"
            + currentdate.getSeconds();
```

Comment: Minutes and seconds should be extended to have 2 digits, like it is done at days and months.

Answer (score 9):

Short and simple:-

```
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString());
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

Comment: This has already been mentioned in other answers, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69263072/2227743) for example.

Answer (score 8):

Basic JS (good to learn): we use the Date() function and do all that we need to show the date and day in our custom format.

```js
var myDate = new Date();

let daysList = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
let monthsList = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Aug', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];


let date = myDate.getDate();
let month = monthsList[myDate.getMonth()];
let year = myDate.getFullYear();
let day = daysList[myDate.getDay()];

let today = `${date} ${month} ${year}, ${day}`;

let amOrPm;
let twelveHours = function (){
    if(myDate.getHours() > 12)
    {
        amOrPm = 'PM';
        let twentyFourHourTime = myDate.getHours();
        let conversion = twentyFourHourTime - 12;
        return `${conversion}`

    }else {
        amOrPm = 'AM';
        return `${myDate.getHours()}`}
};
let hours = twelveHours();
let minutes = myDate.getMinutes();

let currentTime = `${hours}:${minutes} ${amOrPm}`;

console.log(today + ' ' + currentTime);
```

---

Node JS (quick & easy): Install the npm pagckage using (*npm install date-and-time*), then run the below.

```
let nodeDate = require('date-and-time');
let now = nodeDate.format(new Date(), 'DD-MMMM-YYYY, hh:mm:ss a');
console.log(now);
```

Answer (score 7):

By using default `Date()`

```
const now = new Date();
console.log(now); // Output: Thu Sep 23 2021 13:24:52 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

For different date and time formats you can use `toLocaleString()`:

1. Short date format: `MM/DD/YYYY`

   ```
   const now = new Date();
   const formattedDate = now.toLocaleString('en-US', { dateStyle: 'short' });
   console.log(formattedDate);
   // Output: "9/23/2021"
   ```
2. Long date format: `Weekday, Month Day, Year`

   ```
   const now = new Date();
   const formattedDate = now.toLocaleString('en-US', { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' });
   console.log(formattedDate);
   // Output: "Thursday, September 23, 2021"
   ```
3. Short time format: `HH:MM AM/PM`

   ```
   const now = new Date();
   const formattedDate = now.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeStyle: 'short' });
   console.log(formattedDate);
   // Output: "1:24 PM"
   ```
4. Long time format: `HH:MM:SS AM/PM Timezone`

   ```
   const now = new Date();
   const formattedDate = now.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric', hour12: true, timeZoneName: 'short' });
   console.log(formattedDate);
   // Output: "1:24:52 PM EDT"
   ```
5. ISO 8601 format: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ`

   ```
   const now = new Date();
   const isoDate = now.toISOString();
   console.log(isoDate);
   // Output: "2021-09-23T17:24:52.740Z"
   ```

Answer (score 6):

I have found the simplest way to get current date and time in JavaScript from here - [How to get current Date and Time using JavaScript](http://www.codexworld.com/how-to-guides/get-current-date-time-using-javascript/)

```
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var CurrentDateTime = date+' '+time;
```

Answer (score 5):

`getDay()` gets the day of the week.  `3` is Wednesday.  You want `getDate()`, that will return `18`.

Also `getMonth()` starts at `0`, you need to add `1` to get `4` (April).

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/4zVxp/

Answer (score 5):

You need to use getDate() to get the date part. The getDay() function returns the day number (Sunday = 0, Monday = 1...), and the getMonth() returns a 0 based index, so you need to increment it by 1.

```
 var currentdate = new Date(); 

 var datetime = "Last Sync: " + currentdate.getDate() + "/"+  (parseInt(currentdate.getMonth())    + 1)
   + "/" + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
   + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
   + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentdate.getSeconds();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
const date = new Date()
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString("en-us", {timeStyle: "medium"})) // Only Time 
console.log(date.toLocaleString()) // For both Date and Time
```

[For Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)

Answer (score 3):

```
function getTimeStamp() {
       var now = new Date();
       return ((now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (now.getDate()) + '/' + now.getFullYear() + " " + now.getHours() + ':'
                     + ((now.getMinutes() < 10) ? ("0" + now.getMinutes()) : (now.getMinutes())) + ':' + ((now.getSeconds() < 10) ? ("0" + now
                     .getSeconds()) : (now.getSeconds())));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

get current date and time

```
var now = new Date(); 
  var datetime = now.getFullYear()+'/'+(now.getMonth()+1)+'/'+now.getDate(); 
  datetime += ' '+now.getHours()+':'+now.getMinutes()+':'+now.getSeconds();
```

Answer (score 3):

This question is quite old and the answers are too. Instead of those monstrous functions, we now can use moment.js to get the current date, which actually makes it very easy. All that has to be done is including [***moment.js***](http://momentjs.com/) in our project and get a well formated date, for example, by:

```
moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
```

I think that makes it way easier to handle dates in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

.getDay returns day of week. You need .getDate instead.
.getMonth returns values from 0 to 11. You'll need to add 1 to the result to get "human" month number.

Answer (score 2):

*This little code is easy and works everywhere.*

```
<p id="dnt"></p>
<script>
document.getElementById("dnt").innerHTML = Date();
</script>
```

*there is room to design*

Answer (score 2):

```
function UniqueDateTime(format='',language='en-US'){
    //returns a meaningful unique number based on current time, and milliseconds, making it virtually unique
    //e.g : 20170428-115833-547
    //allows personal formatting like more usual :YYYYMMDDHHmmSS, or YYYYMMDD_HH:mm:SS
    var dt = new Date();
    var modele="YYYYMMDD-HHmmSS-mss";
    if (format!==''){
      modele=format;
    }
    modele=modele.replace("YYYY",dt.getFullYear());
    modele=modele.replace("MM",(dt.getMonth()+1).toLocaleString(language, {minimumIntegerDigits: 2, useGrouping:false}));
    modele=modele.replace("DD",dt.getDate().toLocaleString(language, {minimumIntegerDigits: 2, useGrouping:false}));
    modele=modele.replace("HH",dt.getHours().toLocaleString(language, {minimumIntegerDigits: 2, useGrouping:false}));
    modele=modele.replace("mm",dt.getMinutes().toLocaleString(language, {minimumIntegerDigits: 2, useGrouping:false}));
    modele=modele.replace("SS",dt.getSeconds().toLocaleString(language, {minimumIntegerDigits: 2, useGrouping:false}));
    modele=modele.replace("mss",dt.getMilliseconds().toLocaleString(language, {minimumIntegerDigits: 3, useGrouping:false}));
    return modele;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dt= new Date();
alert(dt.toISOString().substring(8,10) + "/" + 
dt.toISOString().substring(5,7)+ "/" + 
dt.toISOString().substring(0,4) + " " + 
dt.toTimeString().substring(0,8))
```

Comment: Please include explanation of what your code does and how it answers the question. If you get a code snippet as an answer, you may not know what to do with it. Answer should give the OP and future visitors guidance on how to debug and fix their problem. Pointing out, what the idea behind your code is, greatly helps in understanding the issue and applying or modifying your solution.

Comment: It is primitive for you and now. What about in a year? What about for somebody who does not read JavaScript as fluently as you do? I suggest you add something along the lines of *Use new instance of `Date`. Parse date components from `toISOString()` and add time from `toTimeString()`.*.

Comment: This approach is not an optimal one. Hard to read the code, involves unnecessary parsing. E.g. `toISOString().substring(8,10)` is the same as `getFullYear()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var datetime = new Date().toLocaleString().slice(0,9) +" "+new Date(new Date()).toString().split(' ')[4];
console.log(datetime);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think i am very late to share my answer, but i think it will be worth.

```
function __getCurrentDateTime(format){
    var dt=new Date(),x,date=[];
    date['d']=dt.getDate();
    date['dd']=dt.getDate()>10?dt.getDate():'0'+dt.getDate();
    date['m']=dt.getMonth()+1;
    date['mm']=(dt.getMonth()+1)>10?(dt.getMonth()+1):'0'+(dt.getMonth()+1);
    date['yyyy']=dt.getFullYear();
    date['yy']=dt.getFullYear().toString().slice(-2);
    date['h']=(dt.getHours()>12?dt.getHours()-12:dt.getHours());
    date['hh']=dt.getHours();
    date['mi']=dt.getMinutes();
    date['mimi']=dt.getMinutes()<10?('0'+dt.getMinutes()):dt.getMinutes();
    date['s']=dt.getSeconds();
    date['ss']=dt.getSeconds()<10?('0'+dt.getSeconds()):dt.getSeconds();
    date['sss']=dt.getMilliseconds();
    date['ampm']=(dt.getHours()>=12?'PM':'AM');
    x=format.toLowerCase();
    x=x.indexOf('dd')!=-1?x.replace(/(dd)/i,date['dd']):x.replace(/(d)/i,date['d']);
    x=x.indexOf('mm')!=-1?x.replace(/(mm)/i,date['mm']):x.replace(/(m)/i,date['m']);
    x=x.indexOf('yyyy')!=-1?x.replace(/(yyyy)/i,date['yyyy']):x.replace(/(yy)/i,date['yy']);
    x=x.indexOf('hh')!=-1?x.replace(/(hh)/i,date['hh']):x.replace(/(h)/i,date['h']);
    x=x.indexOf('mimi')!=-1?x.replace(/(mimi)/i,date['mimi']):x.replace(/(mi)/i,date['mi']);
    if(x.indexOf('sss')!=-1){   x=x.replace(/(sss)/i,date['sss']);  }
    x=x.indexOf('ss')!=-1?x.replace(/(ss)/i,date['ss']):x.replace(/(s)/i,date['s']);
    if(x.indexOf('ampm')!=-1){  x=x.replace(/(ampm)/i,date['ampm']);    }
    return x;
}

console.log(__getCurrentDateTime());  //returns in dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS
console.log(__getCurrentDateTime('dd-mm-yyyy'));    //return in 05-12-2016
console.log(__getCurrentDateTime('dd/mm*yyyy'));    //return in 05/12*2016
console.log(__getCurrentDateTime('hh:mimi:ss'));    //return in 13:05:30
```

console.log(__getCurrentDateTime('h:mi:ss ampm'));    //return in 1:5:30 PM

Answer (score 1):

I needed to figure this out for a slate in after effects. Here's what I came up with after taking elements from a few different sources -- Formatting is MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM

```
D = new Date(Date(00));
M = D.getMonth()+1;
H = D.getHours();
Mi = D.getMinutes();

N = "AM"
if (H >= 12)
N = "PM"
if (H > 12)
{
H = H-12
}

amtOfZeroes = 2;
isNeg = false;

if (M < 0)
{
M = Math.abs(M);
isNeg = true;
}
Mo = Math.round(M) + "";
while(Mo.length < amtOfZeroes)
{

Mo = "0" + Mo; 
}
if (isNeg)
Mo = "-" + Mo;

if (H < 0)
{
H = Math.abs(H);
isNeg = true;
}
Ho = Math.round(H) + "";
while(Ho.length < amtOfZeroes)
{
Ho = "0" + Ho; 
}
if (isNeg)
Ho = "-" + Ho;

if (Mi < 0)
{
Mi = Math.abs(Mi);
isNeg = true;
}
Min = Math.round(Mi) + "";
while(Min.length < amtOfZeroes)
{
Min = "0" + Min; 
}
if (isNeg)
Min = "-" + Min;

T = Ho + ":" + (Min)

Mo + "/" + D.getDate() + "/" + D.getFullYear() + "  " + T + " " + N
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone is in search of function

```
console.log(formatAMPM());
function formatAMPM() {
  var date = new Date();
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var seconds = date.getSeconds();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  return strTime = date.getMonth() + '/' + date.getDay()+'/'+date.getFullYear()+' '+ hours + ':' + minutes +':'+ seconds + " " +ampm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function display_c(){   
    var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds    
    mytime = setTimeout('display_ct()', refresh)    
}

function display_ct() {

    var strcount    
    var currentdate = new Date();

    document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = currentdate.toDateString() + " " + currentdate.getHours() + ":" + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentdate.getSeconds();

    tt = display_c();   
}


id = 'ct'     // Replace in Your id

onload = "display_ct();"     // Type inside a Body Tag
```

Answer (score 0):

My well intended answer is to use this tiny bit of JS: https://github.com/rhroyston/clock-js

```
clock.now   --> 1462248501241
clock.time  --> 11:08 PM
clock.weekday   --> monday
clock.day   --> 2
clock.month --> may
clock.year  --> 2016
clock.since(1462245888784)  --> 44 minutes
clock.until(1462255888784)  --> 2 hours
clock.what.time(1462245888784)  --> 10:24 PM
clock.what.weekday(1461968554458)   --> friday
clock.what.day('14622458887 84')    --> 2
clock.what.month(1461968554458) --> april
clock.what.year('1461968554458')    --> 2016
clock.what.time()   --> 11:11 PM
clock.what.weekday('14619685abcd')  -->     clock.js error : expected unix timestamp as argument
clock.unit.seconds  --> 1000
clock.unit.minutes  --> 60000
clock.unit.hours    --> 3600000
clock.unit.days --> 86400000
clock.unit.weeks    --> 604800000
clock.unit.months   --> 2628002880
clock.unit.years    --> 31536000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple and superb

```js
 $(document).ready(function () { 
            var fpsOut = document.getElementById('myTime');
            setInterval(function () {
                var d = new Date(); 
                fpsOut.innerHTML = d;
            }, 1000);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myTime"></div>
```

please find the below fiddler for the example

http://jsfiddle.net/4zVxp/483/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my work around clock full format with day, date, year and time
and make Sure the date of your PC is set to the right date and if you are using PHP make sure in php.ini  date.timezone= xx where xx your current timezone

```js
function startTime()
{
    var today=new Date();
    //                   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10    11  12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30   31   32   33
    var suffixes = ['','st','nd','rd','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','st','nd','rd','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','st','nd','rd'];

    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0] = "Sunday";
    weekday[1] = "Monday";
    weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
    weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
    weekday[4] = "Thursday";
    weekday[5] = "Friday";
    weekday[6] = "Saturday";

    var month = new Array(12);
    month[0] = "January";
    month[1] = "February";
    month[2] = "March";
    month[3] = "April";
    month[4] = "May";
    month[5] = "June";
    month[6] = "July";
    month[7] = "August";
    month[8] = "September";
    month[9] = "October";
    month[10] = "November";
    month[11] = "December";

    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=(weekday[today.getDay()] + ',' + " " + today.getDate()+'<sup>'+suffixes[today.getDate()]+'</sup>' + ' of' + " " + month[today.getMonth()] + " " + today.getFullYear() + ' Time Now ' + today.toLocaleTimeString());
    t=setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}
```

```css
<style>
sup {
        vertical-align: super;
        font-size: smaller;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<html>
<body onload="startTime()">
<div id="txt"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use :
new Date().toLocaleDateString() to fetch current date and
new Date().toLocaleTimeString() to fetch current time

Ex:

```
const date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
const time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let currentTime = `${new Date().getHours()}:${new Date().getMinutes()}:${new Date().getSeconds()}
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This example of UK Time Zone..  set  `offset` for specific **Time Zone**.
Example : for India : +05:30 , UK : +1

```
 function realUKTime() {
        // create Date object for current location
        var d = new Date();
        offset ='+1';
       
        // convert to msec
        // subtract local time zone offset
        // get UTC time in msec
        var utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

        // create new Date object for different city
        // using supplied offset
        var nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));

        // return time as a string
        var s = nd.getSeconds();
        var i = nd.getMinutes();
        var h = nd.getHours();
        var cDate =  nd.getDate();
        var m =  nd.getUTCMonth();
        var y = nd.getFullYear();

       var newUkTime = nd.toDateString() + " "+ (Number(h)-1)+":"+i+':'+s
        $("#realTime").html(newUkTime);

    }

    setInterval(realUKTime(),1000);
```

> **Output** ::  Mon Dec 27 2021 12:6:3

Answer (score -2):

Check this out may be it will work for you

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var dayarray=new Array("Sunday","Monday",
 "Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday")

var montharray=new Array("January","February","March",
 "April","May","June","July","August","September",
 "October","November","December")

function getthedate(){
var mydate=new Date()
var year=mydate.getYear()
if (year < 1000)
year+=1900
var day=mydate.getDay()
var month=mydate.getMonth()
var daym=mydate.getDate()
if (daym<10)
daym="0"+daym
var hours=mydate.getHours()
var minutes=mydate.getMinutes()
var seconds=mydate.getSeconds()
var dn="AM"
if (hours>=12)
dn="PM"
if (hours>12){
hours=hours-12
}
if (hours==0)
hours=12
if (minutes<=9)
minutes="0"+minutes
if (seconds<=9)
seconds="0"+seconds
//change font size here
var cdate="<small><font color='000000' face='Arial'><b>"+dayarray[day]+", 
    "+montharray[month]+" "+daym+", "+year+" "+hours+":"
 +minutes+":"+seconds+" "+dn
    +"</b></font></small>"
if (document.all)
document.all.clock.innerHTML=cdate
else if (document.getElementById)
document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML=cdate
else
document.write(cdate)
}
 if (!document.all&&!document.getElementById)
  getthedate()
  function goforit(){
  if (document.all||document.getElementById)
 setInterval("getthedate()",1000)
}

 </script>

enter code here

 <span id="clock"></span>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try with this:

```
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date+' '+time;
```

Output:

```
2022-3-3 15:52:45
```

Answer (score -4):

```html
<p id="DateTimeBox">Click The Button To Show Date And Time</p>
<button onclick="ShowDate();"> Show Date </button>
<script>
  function ShowDate() {
    document.getElementById('DateTimeBox').innerHTML = Date();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You should include some commentary and not have just a code-only post.