# JavasScript | Display Current Date

Tags: javascript, date, time

So the problem is to **Display the current date but not the time. The date must be synced with the computer's time.** ,**and a pop up display message should say Good Morning if the time is AM and Good Evening if the time PM.** I can do the pop up message but i don't know how to sync it to the time. Please i need help. thanks.

Comment: I hate asking obvious, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
var d    = new Date(),
    pm   = d.getHours() > 12,
    date = d.getDate() + '-' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '-' + d.getFullYear();

alert('Good ' + (pm ? 'evening' : 'morning') + ', it\'s ' + date);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YSUng/)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library. It's excellent for formatting dates, and also has international language support.

For example, this will give you the current date:

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY');
```

And this will give you 'AM' or 'PM':

```
moment().format("A");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access all of these properties individually using the [Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) in JavaScript. Here's a quick example using JavaScript to display the date in the dateMonthYear div. [jsFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/spaceagecrystal/qKAk3/2/).

Also there is a great example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211145/getting-current-date-and-time-in-javascript?rq=1) that explains why the + 1 needs to be added to currentdate.getMonth(), and also how to use the protoype constructor for the Date object to create a new method of the Date object for date and time with your particular formatting.

HTML

```
<div id="dateMonthYear"></div>
```

JS

```
var currentdate = new Date();
var dateMonthYear = currentdate.getDate() + "/" + (currentdate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + currentdate.getFullYear();
document.getElementById("dateMonthYear").innerHTML= dateMonthYear;
if (currentdate.getHours() < 12) {
    alertMessage = "Good Morning."
} else {
    alertMessage = "Good Evening."
}
alert(alertMessage);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function funampm()
{
var today=new Date();
var h=today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes();
if(h>11)
{
    alert("Good Evening");
}
else {
    alert("Good Morning");
}
}
```