# Passing current system time in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, date, date-format

I am new to web application making a online examination website and have a script which is currently taking static date and time. I want it to the system current date and time plus(add current time with) a value from jsp variable(i.e the time interval of the examination) 
Currently my javascript is as follows:-

```
<script language="JavaScript">
TargetDate = "12/26/2013 5:00 AM";
BackColor = "palegreen";
ForeColor = "navy";
CountActive = true;
CountStepper = -1;
LeadingZero = true;
DisplayFormat = "%%D%% Days, %%H%% Hours, %%M%% Minutes, %%S%% Seconds.";
FinishMessage = "It is finally here!";
</script>
```

Add i have a jsp variable "t" to be added to current time as to make the target time=current time + "t".

Note- This is for countdown timer in my webpage.

Thankyou.

Comment: Please refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211145/getting-current-date-and-time-in-javascript) too. And for adding javascript and jsp variable, you may have to use a hidden variable to write jsp value to it, and use javascript to read it and add what you are saying.

Comment: Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.

Comment: @sivatumma I have that variable "t" in my jsp but how to add it to the script?? can i just use <%t%>.

Comment: Though I am not having tomcat installed, I try to tell you theoretically. You will put your jsp variable in a hidden field in your html like this : `<input type = "hidden" value="<%= t %>" id="myJspVar">`. Now in your javascript, you will take this using `var myJavascriptVar = 'some value'; alert(document.getElementById('myJspVar').value + myJavascriptVar);`. Please note this is how you could do, but you have to fiddle as I do not have tomcat to test for correctness.

Comment: @sivatumma i am done with the system date stuff thanks a lot but i am unable to get how to add my jsp variable to my current minutes

Comment: now it would be better to show your code. copy a short snippet where you are trying to add them ...

Comment: `<script language="JavaScript">
 var currentdate = new Date(); 
 var myvar=document.getElementById("myJspVar");
 var minute=currentdate.getMinutes()+myvar; 
TargetDate = "12/25/2013 11:"+minute+" PM";
BackColor = "palegreen";
ForeColor = "navy";
CountActive = true;
CountStepper = -1;
LeadingZero = true;
DisplayFormat = "%%D%% Days, %%H%% Hours, %%M%% Minutes, %%S%% Seconds.";
FinishMessage = "It is finally here!";
</script>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scrptlets` or `expression` .

```
<script language="JavaScript">
     TargetDate = "<%=new java.util.Date()%>";
     . . . 
</script>
```

For learning more , refer **[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaov.html)**

**For Date Formatting (Till Java7)**  :

You can use **[Simple DateFormat format codes](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm)** .

```
   <%
      Date dNow = new Date( );
      SimpleDateFormat ft =new SimpleDateFormat ("MM/dd/yyyy  hh:mm a");

   %>

   <script language="JavaScript">
         TargetDate = "<%=ft.format(dNow)%>";
         . . . 
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks but how to get this in the format "12/26/2013 5:00 AM"?

Answer (score 0):

### Poor Answer

> how to get this in the format "12/26/2013 5:00 AM"?

To directly answer your question… To do so on the Java side on the server (as opposed to client-side in JavaScript), use the bundled classes [java.text.DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) and java.text.SimpleDateFormat.

### Better Answer: Joda-Time

A better answer is to tell you to avoid java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar classes. They are notoriously badly designed and implemented. Instead use a good date-time library. In Java that means either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (open-source third-party library) or the new [java.time.* classes](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) defined by [JSR 310](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) and bundled with [Java 8](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) and meant to supplant the old j.u.Date/Calendar.

If you literally want only the format like "12/26/2013 5:00 AM", you can define a [pattern in Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#forPattern%28java.lang.String%29). You'll find many examples of this in other questions here on StackOverflow.com.

If you know the user's [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) and [time zone name](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html) you can use those to format the date as a familiar string presentation.

Example code…

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

DateTime now = DateTime.now();

// Style is defined by a pair of letters, one for date portion, the other for time portion.
// Letters are the first letter from: Short/Medium/Long/Full
// This example might be appropriate for a French person in Puducherry India (formerly Pondicherry, ex-colony of France).
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "SS" ).withLocale( Locale.FRENCH ).withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ) );
String dateTimeString = formatter.print( now );
System.out.println( "dateTimeString: " + dateTimeString + " for: " + now );

// By comparison.
DateTimeFormatter formatter_FF = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "FF" ).withLocale( Locale.FRENCH ).withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ) );
String dateTimeString_FF = formatter_FF.print( now );
System.out.println( "dateTimeString_FF: " + dateTimeString_FF + " for: " + now );
```

When run (with my default time zone being US west coast)…

```
dateTimeString: 26/12/13 02:35 for: 2013-12-25T13:05:09.282-08:00
dateTimeString_FF: jeudi 26 décembre 2013 02 h 44 IST for: 2013-12-25T13:14:41.841-08:00
```

### Experiment

Experiment if you wish. For United States, try local of `Locale.US` and time zone of `America/New_York` or `America/Indiana/Knox`.