# get current time from pc and save it in database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a database in mysql named **apply(id, user, time_apply)**. I have set structure for time_apply to "datetime"

I have a php script which is trying to get current **DATE** and **TIME** from a user's pc and store it my database. User's pc can be anywhere in the world.

```
<?php

$timeString='
<script language="javascript">
var today = new Date();
document.write(today);
</script> ';

//id is my database primary key, so I don't insert anything inside

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `apply` VALUES ('', '$session_user_id', '$timeString') "); 


?>
```

The problem is that after mysql_query executed, I cannot insert current user's date and time in my database. I get something like : 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Instead of adding the data through PHP, you can declare the field (time_apply) as TIMESTAMP, and attribute as ON UPDATE CURRENT TIMESTAMP. So that, on adding/pdating the data, the field will have the updated current time.

Comment: Mixing PHP and JavaScript. The JavaScript is run on client-side... by that time you have already executed the SQL query. You need to post back the date to PHP and then store in DataBase.

Comment: @Prava the OP wants to store the client's PC datetime and not his own server DATATIME.

Comment: You need to use AJAX or have Javascript add the time to a hidden field in a form.

Comment: Why is the time on the PC different from the time on the server? Everyone should run time synchronization software these days.

Comment: The only difference would be the time zone. Is that what you're trying to get?

Comment: yes...because my server will be in usa and a user can be in uk, so there will be difference in time.

Comment: If you're trying to get the current time, why does it matter that you get it from the User's PC? The Timezones will be different but that also means the User could change their clock to submit any time they want to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ugly coding (but this is what you wanted ) :)

```
$timeString='
<script language="javascript">
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
    dd="0"+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm="0"+mm
} 

today = mm+"/"+dd+"/"+yyyy + " " +today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes()+":" + today.getSeconds();
document.write(today);
</script> ';


echo "INSERT INTO `apply` VALUES ('test', '1', '$timeString') ";
```

***output***

```
INSERT INTO `apply` VALUES ('test', '1', ' 05/29/2014 22:50:4 ')
```

Comment: looks great... A final question please. This takes the user's PC date time right? Because I want to get the user's date-time not my server's. I was using now() in php before, but that was using server's time.

Comment: yes,here we are taking the users system time by javascript and not the server time

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you would want to capture the client's time but here's how you would do it.

First you'll need to separate your javascript and php script.  You can have php output javascript but not the way you have it written.

You can create a hidden element that gets set whenever the javascript event of your choice fires.  I used the onclick event of the submit button you could use page_load or whatever.  You could then pull that value from the php $_POST variables collection.

```
<script language="javascript">
function submit_OnClick() {
    document.getElementById("clientDate").value =  currentdate.getDate() + "/"
            + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
            + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
            + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
            + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
            + currentdate.getSeconds();
     }
</script> 


<?php

$timeString=$_POST["clientDate"];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Apply (id, user, time_apply) VALUES ('', '$session_user_id', '$timeString') "); 

?>

<form method="post">
    <input type='hidden' id='clientDate' />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id='submitForm' OnClick="submit_OnClick();"/>
    <!-- The rest of your form goes here -->
</form>
```

See this related post for more options and analysis into javascript dates:

[Getting current date and time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211145/getting-current-date-and-time-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You have a complete misunderstanding of how PHP and JS operate. You do not have any actual JS code in your snippet above. You have a PHP **STRING** which happens to contain some text that LOOKS like Javascript.

But since PHP has absolutely NO clue as to what JS is, let alone execute it, you're literally stuffing your JS code into MySQL as a date value. MySQL is of course saying "what the heck is this" and trashing it to the default 0000-00-00 "bad date provided" value.

Remember: PHP executes on the server, JS executes on the client.

There is absolutely **NO** reason to have a client generate dates for use in your server-side DB, when the server-side DB is perfectly capable of generating its own dates:

```
INSERT ... VALUES(..., now());
                       ^^^^^---literally all you need.
```

Comment: The OP wants to store the client's PC datetime and not his own sql server DATATIME

Comment: dont want now() will store my server date time... I want to store date and time from user's pc located anywhere in the world in my database.

Comment: regardles, this comment is correct about how PHP and JS operate.

Answer (score 0):

1) Instead of adding the data through PHP, you can declare the field (time_apply) as TIMESTAMP, and attribute as ON UPDATE CURRENT TIMESTAMP. So that, on adding/pdating the data, the field will have the updated current time.

2) Or else you can use $timeString = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); value for inserting current time.

3) Or else you can use NOW() method for the field for the value while writing the script.

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` will get the server time, not the client time.

Comment: The OP wants to store the client's PC datetime and not his own server DATATIME

Comment: now() will give me servers date and time. I want to store user's pc datea and time

Comment: Then you can use manually as $timeString = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');