# Javascript clock?

Tags: javascript, php, timer, clock

I get the GMT time in PHP and I would like to make it count, like the clocks.

```
<?php $time = gmdate('H:i:s'); ?>

<script>var time = <?php echo($time) ?>;
    setInterval(function() {
        time += 1;
        $("#timediv").text("Current time (GMT): " + time);
        //somehow convert it to 11:44:31 AM ??
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Can seomeon help me?

Comment: Use the clients clock. Otherwise it will drift. And get the current time from the client each time it is updated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211145/getting-current-date-and-time-in-javascript

Answer (score 6):

First of all, relying on setTimeout/setInterval accuracy for displaying time is not a good idea. There are multiple reasons for them not being that accurate, like CPU slowdowns. That's why you should rather use Date object, which uses actual clock.

This is what I do when I want to use my server's time on the client side:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- dateFormat plugin for nice and easy time formatting -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-dateFormat/1.0/jquery.dateFormat.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var clientTime = (new Date()).getTime(),
        serverTime = <?php echo time() ?> * 1000,
        difference = clientTime - serverTime;

    setInterval(function () {
        var now = new Date();

        now.setTime(now.getTime() - difference);

        $("#timediv").text("Current time (GMT): " + $.format.date(now, "hh:mm:ss a"));
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

The key concept behind it is to calculate the **difference** between server time and client time. Then, you normalize your client side (created each time with `new Date()`) with the difference. We are still using setInterval, but even if it's delayed or accelerated for some reason, the time displayed is still correct.

Comment: All of my yes. The only slight thing I would change is to have the `setInterval` be more frequent, such as 100-250 instead of 1000. Reason for this is that it's not completely accurate, and it bothered me a lot on my first clock to see two seconds pass by in a single tick ;)

Comment: but it gives back my time, not GMT (United Kingdom time) :(

Answer (score 1):

I would not follow motanelu's answer but change it to this:

```
<script>var time = Date.parse('<?php echo($time) ?>');
    setInterval(function() {
        time.setSeconds(time.getSeconds() + 1);
        $("#timediv").text("Current time (GMT): " + time);
        //somehow convert it to 11:44:31 AM ??
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

This creates a Date object which can you can format with for example `time.toLocaleTimeString();`

Comment: This will use the client's date, not the server's!

Comment: how will this use the clients date? notice i populate the Date() from the php script :)

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
<?php $time = gmdate('H:i:s'); ?>
```

with

```
<?php $time = gmdate('h:i:s A'); ?>
```

Comment: Why? Explain your answer.

Comment: You've changed from a 24-hours representation to a 12-hour one. Why is that a good idea?

Comment: Did you actually read the question? Especially the part with //somehow convert it to 11:44:31 AM ??

Answer (score -1):

Thank you guys, I made it:

PHP:

```
$time = gmdate('H:i:s');
$time = preg_replace("/^([\d]{1,2})\:([\d]{2})$/", "00:$1:$2", $time);
sscanf($time, "%d:%d:%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
$timeInSeconds = $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds;
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function fromSeconds(sec){
        var d=new Date(0,0,0);
        d.setSeconds(+sec);
        return (d.getHours() ? d.getHours()+":" : "")+d.getMinutes()+":"+d.getSeconds();
    }

    var time = <?php echo($timeInSeconds) ?>;
    var newTime = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        time += 1;
        var newTime = fromSeconds(time);
        $("#timediv").text("The current GMT time is: " + newTime);
    }, 1000);');
    ?>
</script>
```

Comment: This is bad, but you probably won't notice it. Just because you tell the code to run every 1,000 milliseconds, does *not* mean that it will run at *exactly* that time. There is usually a +/- 8 millisecond inaccuracy with every tick. See Robo Robok's answer for how it should be done.

Comment: Why the downvote instead of just upvoting the best answer? As long as the others are not *wrong* (based on the question)?