# Why does this Javascript script not give ant output?

Tags: javascript, date

I want to make a simple live date counter that would output in the html where ever the script is located in the file. Here's the JSFiddle, and here's that script:

```
var today = newDate();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth();
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if (dd = 1 || 21 || 31) {
    dd = dd + 'st'
} else if (dd = 2 || 22) {
    dd = dd + 'nd'
} else if (dd = 3 || 23) {
    dd = dd + 'nd'
} else {
    dd = dd + 'th'
}

if (mm = 0) {
    mm = "JANUARY";
} else if (mm = 1) {
    mm = "FEBRUARY";
} else if (mm = 2) {
    mm = "MARCH";
} else if (mm = 3) {
    mm = "APRIL";
} else if (mm = 4) {
    mm = "MAY";
} else if (mm = 5) {
    mm = "JUNE";
} else if (mm = 6) {
    mm = "JULY";
} else if (mm = 7) {
    mm = "AUGUST";
} else if (mm = 8) {
    mm = "SEPTEMBER";
} else if (mm = 9) {
    mm = "OCTOBER";
} else if (mm = 10) {
    mm = "NOVEMBER";
} else {
    mm = "DECEMBER";
}

today = dd + '|' + mm + '|' + yyyy;
document.write(today);
```

I know that this is the most inefficint and probably incorrect way of writing any code in general (this is the second thing i've ever done in JS.) but please have some acceptance for my stupid mistakes.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Equality test is == assignment is =

Comment: use `==` to test equality, not single `=`, also you can't do this : `dd = 2 || 22` need to have both tests : `dd == 2 || dd == 22`

Comment: Just love this indentation. :)

Comment: also `new Date()` not `newDate()`

Comment: in general, you should learn to read the exceptions in the Developer tools console... learn to use the debugger,  put breakpoints,  etc...

Comment: @DhavalMarthak I would use an array . not a switch.

Comment: @David have a look at my ans... somehow efficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Avoid cascading of if's

```
var month = ["January", "Feb", "March",....,"Dec"];//store array of months as string
var suffix =["st","nd","rd","th"];
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth();
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
var op="";
if(parseInt(dd) > 4)
    op+=dd+""+suffix[3]+"|";
else
    op+=dd+""+suffix[(parseInt(dd)%10)-1]+"|";
op+=month[parseInt(mm)]+"|"+yyyy;
```

**MAKE IT SIMPLE**  [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pycp15vq/1/)

> FYI : just now saw the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211145/getting-current-date-and-time-in-javascript) and  0-11 for months while 0
>   represents Jan and 11 represents Dec

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var today = new Date();
```

instead

```
var today = newDate();
```

And output will be "1st|FEBRUARY|2015"

---

**Update:** (more elegant way)

```js
b=(new Date()).toLocaleString('en-us', {
  day: 'numeric',
  month: "long",
  year: 'numeric'
}).replace(/(\w+) (\d+), (\d+)/, '$2|$1|$3'); // 30|June|2015
dd=parseInt(b, 10);
op='';
suffix =["st","nd","rd","th"];
if(parseInt(dd) > 4)
    op=dd+""+suffix[3];
else
    op=dd+""+suffix[(parseInt(dd)%10)-1];
alert(b.replace(/^\d+/, op))
```

Comment: Today is not the 1st of Feb, is it?

Comment: Yep, this was an answer to subject of this thread: "Why does this Javascript script not give ant output?". Btw maybe this will help somehow: (new Date()).toUTCString().replace(/.* (\d+) (\w{3}) (\d{4}).*/, '$1|$2|$3') ->
"30|Jun|2015"

Answer (score 0):

just write:  `var today = new Date();`

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel, simply use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/):

```js
var d = new Date();

document.write(moment().format('Do|MMMM|YYYY'));
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moment/moment/develop/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: @theRoot It's 23kB ... and for beginners, I would argue that it's easier so that they can focus on what they want to write.

Comment: For beginners to javascript it's highly not recommended

Comment: Let's agree to disagree, then.

Comment: Yes I accept if the OP want's to learn  JS IMO its not recommended..FYI ..I too newbie in JS...@Ja͢ck

Comment: how you are posting answer as comm wiki?

Comment: @theRoot There's a checkbox in the answer box ... you won't get any reputation from up-votes, though.

Comment: when can I use this? when I don't want to be upvoted?@Ja͢ck

Comment: @theRoot Personally I make my answer CW if I vote to close the question; in this case, it's really a bunch of typos that seem to have caused the issues the OP is facing. It doesn't feel right to receive reputation for a question that I want to see closed ;-)

Comment: I agree with you, but we guys(startups) tries to solve questions  posted by newbies who are little lower than us to get reps  :P