# How do I compare today date and time with my string from database?

Tags: javascript

This is my table:

```
|    date    | open  | close |
-----------------------------
| 2016-08-05 | 04:00 | 05:00 |
| 2016-05-05 | 05:00 | 06:00 |
| 2016-09-05 | 06:00 | 07:00 |
```

and I need to make these statements:

```
if ($todaydate == date && open <= $todaytime <=close) {
      // go to some link
}else{
     // failed alert
}
```

How do I get `$todaydate` and `$todaytime`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting current date and time in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211145/getting-current-date-and-time-in-javascript)

Comment: Is this javascript? This looks like MySQL/PHP to me

Comment: JavaScript is a client side language, and databases usually interact with a server side scripting language. Please clarify your question, and add the necessary tags to answer your question.

Comment: hmmm, i made this code in .js file though.

i use getitem ,setitem for database string.

Comment: @NamikazeSheena I've updated my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this entirely in SQL:

```
SELECT NOW() BETWEEN CONCAT(date, ' ', open, ':00') AND CONCAT(date, ' ', close, ':00') AS `store_is_open`
FROM `my_table`
```

In javascript:

```
var openDate = new Date(date + ' ' + open).getTime();
var closeDate = new Date(date + ' ' + close).getTime();
var now = new Date().getTime();

console.log(openDate <= now && now <= closeDate);
```

Comment: ehehe, it seems i have to change my  date format. thank you

Answer (score -1):

You may convert stored date and time into timestamp then you can compare current timestamp to stored timestamp easily.

Comment: oh , i can do that with javascript ?