# How to use toLocaleTimeString 12 hours time without AM/PM abbreviations?

Tags: javascript

I want to show time in 12 hours format without using the `AM` and `PM`. For example `3:45` only and not `3:45 PM` or `3:45 AM`. How I can modify the `toLocaleTimeString()` to not show the `PM` `AM` but in 12 number format?

```js
var minsToAdd = 45;
var time = "15:00";
var newTime = new Date(new Date("2000/01/01 " + time).getTime() + minsToAdd * 60000).toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', hour12: true });
console.log(newTime);
```

Comment: Why don't you extract the required substring out of `newTime`?

Comment: I was hoping to use any built in function from `toLocalTimeString()`

Comment: It doesn't make sense, and that's why there doesn't seem any ready-made option available to do this.

Comment: There's no preset to do that you'll just have to grab a substring that doesn't contain AM/PM

Comment: Follow this link: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211145/getting-current-date-and-time-in-javascript) it will show you all you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.toLocaleTimeString() did not have any override to do so.

There are multiple ways to do so.

Replace AM/PM by blank:

```
    var minsToAdd = 45;
    var time = "15:00";
    var newTime = new Date(new Date("2000/01/01 " + time).getTime() + minsToAdd * 60000).toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', hour12: true });
    console.log(newTime.replace("AM","").replace("PM",""));
```

Using custom JavaScript function:

```
   function formatTime(d) {
      function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'')+n}
      var h = d.getHours();
      return (h%12 || 12) + ':' + z(d.getMinutes());
    }

    var minsToAdd = 45;
    var time = "15:00";
    var newTime = new Date(new Date("2000/01/01 " + time).getTime() + minsToAdd * 60000);
    console.log(formatTime(newTime));
```

Answer (score 2):

it's very ez.

```js
    const date24 = new Date();
    const data24Time = date24.toLocaleTimeString('en-IT', { hour12: false })
    console.log("24 h : ",data24Time)
    // 24 h :  20:26:09
    
    
    const date12 = new Date();
    const data12Time = date12.toLocaleTimeString('en-IT')
    console.log("12 h : ",data12Time)
    // 12 h :  8:26:09 PM
    
    
    
    
    // toLocaleTimeString('{languege for show time}-{languege for set}')
```

Answer (score 1):

formats below assume the local time zone of the locale;
 America/Los_Angeles for the US

US English uses 12-hour time with AM/PM
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US'));
 "7:00:00 PM"

For more information, visit official docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the easiest way to do so is by using formatting conventions

just replace 'en-US' with 'it-IT' in your code

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35654479)