# how can get current datetime without submit in form

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

i have a submit form where has a input field for group name. I want to create a group name and stote in the database.  when the group name create thats time i want to pick the current date and store in the model class propert. please give me suggestion. Advance thank you.

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="DateTime.Date" class="form-control" />
<input asp-for="Name" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" 
placeholder="Group name">

 <script>
    $(function () {
        //Date picker
        $('#reservationdate').datetimepicker({
            format: 'L',
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
        });
    }
</script>
```

model property
`public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }`
`public string Name { get; set; }`

Comment: Are you looking for getting current date and time in js? Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211145/getting-current-date-and-time-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution-1:

If you are using SQL server then directly use **GETDATE(**) method in your insert and update queries.

### Solution-2:

In your HTTP GET method when the page is loaded initialize the property as follow i.e.

```
    // Initialization.
    MyModel model = new MyModel();
    
    // Settings.
    model.DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

Then in your CSHTML file do following i.e.

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DateTime, new { @readonly = "readonly", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DateTime), @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

The above HTML hidden field will preserve the datetime value, but, know that the time might not be accurate as it is not exact current, so, I recommend setting current date via database is right choice.

Answer (score 1):

don't get the date from `client side` get it form the `server side`

use `DateTime` in c# to get the current date and store it

`var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");`
or use any date format you like

Comment: i do not want to write hradcore , i want when i create a group that's time pike the current date, i have not option to write manually because this property data will be pass in the business object  using mapper, like this
 var group = _mapper.Map<Group>(this);
            _groupService.CreateGroup(group);

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem. Not sure why this has got a upvote!