# HTML Button with time condition

Tags: html, button

I want an html button with link to be opened after particular time.

For example a **button with link [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) which would be opened after 04/10/2021 08:30pm +0530 GMT**

THANK YOU ALL ..

Comment: And what's your question about this? What have you tried to achieve that? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

**HTML:**

```
<button id="my_button" type="button" disabled>Hello World!</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = new Date('2021-10-05');
if (d1 >= d2) document.getElementById('my_button').disabled = false;
```

This will compare the two *Date()* variables and if **d1** is equal or greater than **d2**, it will set the disabled attribute of the button to false.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to disable the button at first and then using js to enable it when the exact date and time are matched

```
<button type="button" id="myBtn" disabled">Please wait...</button>
```

Now we can just use js to first get an object to our button element and then using the Date() constructor to match the exact date and time for our input, enabling the button

```
var myBtn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
var currenttime = new Date(); //Date object
```

we can now just use the Date object to get current time in our format nd then remove the disable attribute from the button

```
if (currenttime === giventime)  $("#myBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

[Getting current date and time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211145/getting-current-date-and-time-in-javascript)