ISO-8601(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX) format in micronaut HttpResponse not working
ISO-8601(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX) format in micronaut HttpResponse not working.
We need date in yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX format, however deserialize not converting in required format.
Controller
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;

import io.micronaut.http.*;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
import io.micronaut.scheduling.TaskExecutors;
import io.micronaut.scheduling.annotation.ExecuteOn;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


@AllArgsConstructor
@Controller
@Slf4j
@ExecuteOn(TaskExecutors.BLOCKING)
public class LogisticsController1 {

  @Get("/test")
  public Mono<HttpResponse<Object>> getRes() throws ParseException, JsonProcessingException {

    String d="2024-05-01T19:52:33.411Z";
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
    Date date2=simpleDateFormat.parse(d);
    TestDate date11=new TestDate();
    date11.setDate(date2);
    return Mono.just(buildResponse(date11));

  }

  public HttpResponse<Object> buildResponse(TestDate date11) throws JsonProcessingException {
    return HttpResponse.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(date11);
  }


}

DTO:
import io.micronaut.serde.annotation.Serdeable;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.Date;

@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Serdeable
public class TestDate {
    //@JsonFormat( shape = STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
    Date  date;
}

API Response :
Actual :
{     "date": "2024-05-01T19:52:33.411Z" }
Updated
Expected Result:
{     "date": "2024-05-01T19:52:33.411+00:00" }
==================================
Things tried:
Looks like JsonFormat does not ISO-8601, other formats are working.
@JsonFormat( shape = STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
Date  date;


Thate actual date is represented in a different time zone, which means it has a different offset from UTC than 0… Is there a specific reason for you to use the long outdated java.util.Date instead of a e.g. java.time.OffsetDateTime?

Use not java.util.Date but java.time.Instant most probably. Do all your datetime strings end in Z? I mean, they should do (unless they end in some other timezone) if you want to maintain the greatest accuracy about a particular point in (universal) time

Current Long (live) time format: Detailed
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65871072

What you can do is simply use java.time classes for it. It may be possible with a SimpleDateFormat, too, but I don't think libraries that old should be recommended…
You should pass the desired offset / zone id when generating the desired output. Here's a simple possibility that uses an OffsetDateTime:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String d = "2024-05-01T19:52:33.411Z";          
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(d);
    OffsetDateTime odt2 = odt.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.ofHoursMinutes(5, 30));
    System.out.println(odt);
    System.out.println(odt2);
}

The output of this is
2024-05-01T19:52:33.411Z
2024-05-02T01:22:33.411+05:30

As you can see, the base is the instant defined in String at the beginning of the code and it gets translated / transformed to a different offset while staying the same moment in time.
In general, the comment by g00se is an even better approach because it stores moments in time in the class meant exactly for that: java.time.Instant, which can also be formatted or used to create an OffsetDateTime or a ZonedDateTime.

Thank you for response, we have some limitation to use only Date due to legacy code.

OK, sure, in that case you probably must use Dates. But be aware of the compatibility methods that convert Dates to Instants and the other way round… they might be helpful!
