Swagger UI displaying LocalDateTime with milliseconds despite format specification
I am encountering an issue with Swagger UI in my Spring Boot application where datetime values are displayed with milliseconds (2024-05-13T11:20:24.151Z) despite specifying a datetime format without milliseconds (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss). This discrepancy is affecting the example values shown in Swagger documentation and the behavior of the "Try it out" feature.
Here is my setup for annotations:
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = )
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
@Schema(example = "2022-10-30T12:45:00", description = "Date time with UTC format")
private LocalDateTime dateTime;


Is this an example request or an example response? Maybe, your @Schema(…) is not taken into account because it has to be inside an @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(…) or an @ApiResponse{…), even more nested, it has to be inside a @Content and the examples may also be nested inside an @Examples. So check out the documentation.

These annotations are in the response medel

I'm not sure how to make the documentation work correctly when annotating the fields of a response model, but the documentation works in my case when I annotate the controller method with an @Operation(summary, description) and all the @ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(responseCode = 400, …, content = @Content(schema = YourApiResponseModel.class), …, examples = {@ExampleObject(name = "name", value = "JSON example", …))).

My bad, I meant that this is a request model

Then use the @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody annotation…

Adding type of string fixed this issue: @Schema(example = "2022-10-30T12:45:00", type = "string", description = "Date time with UTC format")

Cool, I may try that myself later!

Seems like you need to at his if you specify a format. Let me know if it work ok for you.

Current Long (live) time format: Detailed
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65871072

@Schema(example = "2022-10-30T12:45:00", type = "string", description = "Date time")
private LocalDateTime dateTime;

By explicitly setting type = "string", you're instructing Swagger to treat the dateTime field as a string during documentation generation, which can resolve discrepancies in datetime formatting and display within Swagger UI.

type is not required only @Schema(example = "2022-10-30T12:45:00", description = "Date time") this is suffice.

I just tested by removing the type = "string" on one of my LocalDateTime fields, and the milliseconds are present. So looks like it's needed to me.
