# Not receiving date in php file from jquery .post()

Tags: jquery, ajax, date, post

I want to send data to a page using .post(), but the date is not sent, I

```
puzzle = JSON.stringify(puzzle);
        var today = new Date();
        $.post("script/add_grid.php",
        {Puzzle:puzzle, designer:$("#designer").val(), name: "تجربة 1", creation_date:today});
```

add_grid.php

```
$db_word->insert_grid($_REQUEST['Puzzle'],$designer,$name,$creation_date);
```

I am receiving this error message:

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: creation_date in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\entertainment\script\add_grid.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
```

what might be the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you are after:

```
var today = new Date().getTime();
```

if it is the "now" timestamp that you seek.

Comment: thx, the error has gone, but I don't get the date on the server?

Comment: well I am seeking the date only, I am checking this now,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript

Comment: well I will insert the date using MySQl, it solved this problem for now,
but for general use I am sending date as string then parsing it in PHP