# JavaScript Todays date

Tags: javascript, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get current date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript)

I need to get todays date in the format yyyymmdd using JavaScript.

I've used the following code:

```
var d = new Date();
d.getFullYear()+ '' +((d.getMonth()+1)) + '' + d.getDate();
```

But the month and date are returned in single digits, does someone know how to do this?

Comment: @NimChimpsky Agreed. Maybe not an exact duplicate but the top answer certainly answers the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var d = new Date();
        var df = d.getFullYear()
            + ('0' + String(d.getMonth()+1)).substr(-2)
            + ('0' + String(d.getDate())).substr(-2);
        alert(df);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this following way. But you need to write one extra function as below:

```
function getTwoDigit(number) {       
    return (number < 10 ? '0' : '') + number       
}
```

Now you can use that function on your original code.

```
var d = new Date();d.getFullYear()+ '' +(getTwoDigit(d.getMonth()+1)) + '' + getTwoDigit(d.getDate());
```