# How to get current formatted date dd/mm/yyyy in Javascript and append it to an input

Tags: javascript, html, input, tags, hidden

I would like to add a current date to a hidden HTML tag so that it can be sent to the server:

```
<input type="hidden" id="DATE" name="DATE" value="WOULD_LIKE_TO_ADD_DATE_HERE">
```

How can I add a formatted date to the VALUE attribute?

Comment: First thing: don't mix Java with Javascript (don't even split the words Java and Script!). They are completely different languages.

Comment: Do you need the client's local date? Could be an option to use the server's date?

Comment: `(new Date()).toLocaleDateString('en-GB')` is literally all you need to get the UK format date as per OP's question.

Comment: `new Date().toLocaleDateString().padStart(10, '0')`

Comment: Don't do this. The server knows the current date and time and should not trust the value sent by the client because it is trivial to modify the value of a hidden input.

Comment: Try this:
`const formatDate = (dateString) => {
        const date = new Date(dateString);
        const options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
        return date.toLocaleDateString("en-GB",options);
    };`

Answer (score 705, accepted):

I hope this is what you want:

```
const today = new Date();
const yyyy = today.getFullYear();
let mm = today.getMonth() + 1; // Months start at 0!
let dd = today.getDate();

if (dd < 10) dd = '0' + dd;
if (mm < 10) mm = '0' + mm;

const formattedToday = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

document.getElementById('DATE').value = formattedToday;
```

[How do I get the current date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript)

Comment: For most uses, replace the last line with "return today;"

Comment: This is helpful, but confirms that Javascript is insanely inefficient at getting a formatted date returned. It's unfathomable to have to write more than one line of code to do this...

Comment: `new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString();`

Comment: @WhereDatApp.com Is this solution work cross browsers?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=toLocaleString()
@abdallaarbab

Comment: is there any js frameworks which has good date api support ?

Comment: new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10).split('-').reverse().join('/') works good for me.

Comment: date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB')

Comment: Reuse of variable 'today' this way is not a good practise

Comment: @SumanthVarada you can have a look at momentjs here: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: `new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString().split(',')[0]` for the current date in dd/mm/yyyy format only.

Comment: new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString().slice(0,10);

Comment: `new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString();` this gives different formatting results for safari and chrome. Do check before using it.

Comment: new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10)

Comment: new Date().toLocaleDateString() 

this will give date in this format "04/04/2020"

Comment: var DATE_NOW = DATE('d','m','y','-') 
 function DATE(a,b,c,e){
  var d = new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString().split(',')[0];
  d = d.split('.');
  var as = { d:d[0] ,m:d[1] ,y:d[2] };
  return as[a]+e+as[b]+e+as[c];
 }

Comment: Oded's answer is so much shorter than importing a library with 5697 lines of code

Comment: new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString().replace(/(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*?),.*$/,"$3-$2-$1")

Comment: Use `Number(2).toString().padStart(2, 0)` for leading zeros

Answer (score 248):

I honestly suggest that you use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com). Just download `moment.min.js` and then use this snippet to get your date in whatever format you want:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

     // set an element
     $("#date").val( moment().format('MMM D, YYYY') );

     // set a variable
     var today = moment().format('D MMM, YYYY');

});
</script>
```

Use following chart for date formats:

[image]

Comment: simple and effective solution to all date display problems in JavaScript

Comment: I will definitely use moment.js from now on. Very easy and very effective to use. @Ali thanks a lot.

Comment: You can parse dates like this: moment('26/04/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

Comment: can moment get date like "3rd friday of sept"?

Comment: @tatmanblue Yeah you can.

moment().format('Do dddd of MMMM')

If you don't want it to show the full day or month name, then you can cut it down from 4 d's or M's to 3 instead.

Comment: btw moment.js is NOT a small library

Comment: new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10).split('-').reverse().join('/') works good for me. – Sasikumar

Comment: For those who want similar functionality with a smaller footprint, Day.js is excellent! https://www.npmjs.com/package/dayjs

Comment: hey jQuery, how have you been

Comment: I find avoiding large packages on client is better. I'm currently weening off Moment for custom Date() code

Comment: Even *the people who make Moment* are recommending you switch to a different library.

Answer (score 155):

```
<input type="hidden" id="date"/>
<script>document.getElementById("date").value = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10)</script>
```

Comment: d.toJSON().slice(0,10).split('-').reverse().join('/')

Comment: Quickest way to do it without external libraries. Very good.

Comment: An alternative to @Gaurav's solution for those of us who need the date in ISO fomat: `new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,'/')`

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Comment: new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString().split(',')[0]

Comment: date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB');

Comment: So far the coolest

Comment: to format in dd/mm/yyyy
`new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10).split('-').reverse().join('/')`

Comment: This is the slickest date format method I have ever seen.

Comment: This is so ugly, but it seems to be the best you can do with vanilla JS. +1

Comment: Why `toJSON` insteadof `toISOString`?

Comment: do not fall for `toLocaleString` its always based on current system settings, tests will fail every region.

Answer (score 4):

To get current date/time in javascript:

```
var date = new Date();
```

If you need milliseconds for easy server-side interpretation use

```
var value = date.getTime();
```

For formatting dates into a user readable string see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Then just write to hidden field:

```
document.getElementById("DATE").value = value;
```

Comment: or just `document.getElementById('DATE').value = (new Date()).getTime();`

Comment: new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10).split('-').reverse().join('/') works good for me.

Answer (score 2):

By using the value attribute:

```
var today = new Date();
document.getElementById('DATE').value += today;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the DOM's `getElementByid` method:

`document.getElementById("DATE").value = "your date";`

A date can be made with the `Date` class:

`d = new Date();`

(Protip: install a javascript console such as in Chrome or Firefox' Firebug extension. It enables you to play with the DOM and Javascript)

Answer (score -1):

You edit an element's `value` by editing it's `.value` property.

```
document.getElementById('DATE').value = 'New Value';
```