# how do i make the date to appear in dd/MM/yyyy in asp.net after debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime

right now i want to make the date to appear like this dd/mm/yyyy in my front end (as in after debug). but it is appearing like this mm/dd/yyyy. but after i execute the stored procedure in sql server it is the result that i wanted.

this is my code.

```
       <div class="content-frame-bottom type4" style="overflow-x:auto;">    
                    <table width="100%" class="table table-bordered table-condensed">        
                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptReport" runat="server" onitemcommand="rptReport_ItemCommand" >
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                          <tr>
                          <td width="8%" class="table-header2">Date</td>
                          </tr>
                          </HeaderTemplate>

                          <ItemTemplate>
                          <tr>
                            <td><%#  Eval("Date") %> </td>
                          </tr>
                         </ItemTemplate>
                          </asp:Repeater>
                          </div>
```

this is my code in aspx page. how do i make the date to appear in dd/mm/yyyy format. where should i insert it. thanks for helping.

Comment: just this within td `Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("Date")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`

Comment: i tried adding it in the item template but it is not working. it tells me that "Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'". @Suprabhat

Comment: don't know what you have tried but i have simply replaced your `<%#  Eval("Date") %>` with mine `<%#  Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("Date")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") %>` and it's perfectly working for me in my dummy application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try this to convert date to dd/mm/yyyy format

```
<%#Eval("Date", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")%>
```

Comment: How would you do this if the date string was 09102015?

Answer (score 0):

do something like this in server side

```
 string yourdate="01/23/2014";

DateTime timezz = DateTime.Parse(yourdate);
      yourdate = timezz.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

then dynamically add date value to your table

if u want to do it directly in client side then you can use `javascript` or,`String.format` Function

or else if you are downloading moment.js source then simply you can do what ever you want
Example :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

     $("#date").val( moment().format('MMM D, YYYY') );

});
</script>
```

[Reference :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409299/how-to-get-current-formatted-date-dd-mm-yyyy-in-javascript-and-append-it-to-an-i)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Date", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>
```

Or

```
<%# string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", Eval("Date"))%>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. This may work.

```
Eval("Date").ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy");
```

Comment: Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'. @vishu9219

Comment: because your date is already in string format , if it is in date format then only  the above code is working.change it first as date format then use above code it will work