# Why do I not get a formated date with this javascript-script?

Tags: javascript

I am new with javascript, so maybe I missed the obvious.

I have the following script (see also [some other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)):

```
<script>
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleFormat("DD.MM.YYYY");
</script>
```

which I want to use to create a formatted date in jacasvript. If the date is today (26 June 2015) I expect this script to produce the following string:

```
26.06.2015
```

However, what I get is the following:

```
DD.MM.YYYY
```

Is the other answer wrong? How can I get this formatted date **without some extra library**?

I also tried to use `parse` or `format` instead without success.

Comment: Because you're using the wrong format specifiers.  [These are the ones to use](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strftime.html).  Also note that it's a completely non-standard function, that won't work across all browsers.  This is why libraries such as moment.js exist.

Comment: `toLocaleFormat` is not standard. Use `toLocaleDateString`.

Comment: Maybe you could provide a working example?

Comment: `toLocaleDateString` produces an error `invalid language tag: DD.MM.YYYY`.

Comment: [Here's the documentation for `toLocaleDateString`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Comment: @Pointy: Can you give a working example?

Comment: Maybe you can read the docs and do it yourself.

Comment: I read the docs, and I am sure the function `toLocateDateString` cannot solve my problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    <script>
        var d = new Date();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleFormat("%d.%m.%Y");
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409299/how-to-get-current-formatted-date-dd-mm-yyyy-in-javascript-and-append-it-to-an-i) you can create your own function.

```
  var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd
    } 
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm
    } 
    var today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML  = today;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This code 

<p>Click the button to display the date as a string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.toLocaleDateString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
</script>
```