# No format support in Date object

Tags: javascript, date

Was working on a date comparison where in my date shouldn't be greater than today's date. I know the way is to wrap both in `new Date()` and then compare `< or >`. But having some trouble because my format is `dd/mm/yyyy` and any date created with `new Date()` is `mm/dd/yyyy`. Just want to know if there is any way to pass format to `Date` object constructor.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409299/how-to-get-current-formatted-date-dd-mm-yyyy-in-javascript-and-append-it-to-an-i) might already have your answer.

Comment: @Peut22 I know we can split and then re-arrange but it would have been nice if we would pass the format while creating date object itself

Comment: @Pawan try moment.js you can do this moment("25-12-1995", "DD-MM-YYYY");