# Write a function that converts user entered date formatted as M/D/YYYY to a format required by an API (YYYYMMDD)

Tags: javascript

Write a function that converts user entered date formatted as M/D/YYYY to a format required by an API (YYYYMMDD). The parameter "userDate" and the return value are strings.
For example, it should convert user entered date "12/31/2014" to "20141231" suitable for the API.
i tried:

```js
function formatDate(userDate) {
  // format from M/D/YYYY to YYYYMMDD
  a = new Date(userDate);
  y = a.getFullYear();
  m = a.getMonth();
  d = a.getDate();
  return y.toString() + m.toString() + d.toString();
}

console.log(formatDate("12/31/2014"));
```

where is the problem??

Comment: I'm pretty sure the constructor for `Date` doesn't expect a string in an arbitrary format, so there's that.

Comment: Think about what happens when the month (or day) is less than 10. Also, `Date.prototype.getMonth` returns a month index from 0 to 11 for reasons.

Comment: Have you considered just using `<input type="date" />`? It returns a date in `Y-m-d` format, which is unambiguous, and for your API (which is weird) you can just strip the `-`s and you're done.

Comment: For one, your output month is `11`.

Comment: And if this is homework where you solution gets rejected, why not say so? It might be obvious to you, but we can't read your mind.

Comment: getMonth returns a value between 0 and 11, other than that your code works, and you will need to take the input of @Ryan into account.

Comment: my point is how can i get the same date i converted to?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192922/how-do-i-get-a-date-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format

Comment: You just got a whole bunch of answers on that.

Comment: If it's a definite fixed format string then just split it and use the values from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that [`getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) returns a month index from 0 to 11, so December appears as 11 and not 12.

Answer (score 3):

`String#split()` the date on `/` and then concat the generated date, month and year.

```js
function AddLeadingZero(num) {
  return (num < 10 ? '0' : '') + num;
}

function formatDate(userDate) {
  var [month, day, year] = userDate.split('/');
  return year + AddLeadingZero(month) + AddLeadingZero(day); 
}

console.log(formatDate("12/31/2014"));
console.log(formatDate("10/1/2014"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var convertDate = function(usDate) {
  var dateParts = usDate.split(/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})/);
  return dateParts[3] + dateParts[1] +  dateParts[2];
}

var inDate = "12/31/2014";
var outDate = convertDate(inDate);

alert(outDate);
```