# Change date format from yyyy/MM/dd to MM/dd/yyyy in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

**1st attempt**, did this:

```
{{ leads.pgDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy' }}
```

I've also tried:

```
" | date:"MM/dd/yyyy": 'UTC' "
```

**2nd attempt**, went to leadsCtr.js and found

```
$scope.leadsGridOptions = { 
  columnDefs: [ 
    {
      field: 'expected',
      displayName: 'Expected Close Date', width: 150, type: 'date',
cellFilter: 'date:\'MM/dd/yyyy\'' 
    }
  ]
}
```

Added `'type:''date''` and changed cellFilter from `\'sort\'`

**Observations:**

displayName: 'Expected Close Date' **BUT**
the date header in HTML is 'Date of Purchase' - that's why the 2nd attempt didn't work. Also, `cellFilter` is being overridden, that addition didn't alter anything either.

```
{{leads.pgDate.toString()}}
```

adding `toString` didn't change anything- Maybe date is a string?!

**New Problem:**

Cannot find the object that `ng-repeat` is using to populate the fields to see if the date really is a string and I can parse it.

**Questions:**

If date is coming in as String, will the angular filter not work? Is there anyway to override `{{inside the HTML}}` ?

**Answer:**

Used Jimbrooism's suggestion. The wrapper is converting the value back into a date format and the filter works.

Comment: I was trying to edit your post to improve formatting (use markdown for *code* blocks, not *quote* blocks), but that also required some interpretation / reformatting that may affect the code itself, so I stopped. Please try to edit your post, check the formatting help, and use code-formatting, for readability.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.. should I have the comments outside the block?

Comment: If you use backticks (inline code) or four spaces indenting (blocks of code) instead of `>` characters (blockquotes) your code will be formatted in a much more readable way. Check out the [markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: I tried backticks and indenting.. it refuses to show any formatting. Took off the highlights instead, incase that was distracting and added my solution to make it more useful.

Comment: I've tried to show how you could use markdown for formatting. If you go to [the revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36855789/revisions) and click "`side-by-side markdown`" at the top of revision 3 you'll see what I had to change. Good luck to you and thx for helping us improve SO! :-)

Comment: Thanks very much, that _is_ much easier to read!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This
{{convertDate(leads.pgDate) | date:'dd/MMM/yyyy'}}

//JS

```
$scope.convertDate = function convertDate(date){
    return new Date(date);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

if you getting date as a string yyyy-mm-dd then convert this into java script date obj.
After convert it into date obj it is easy to convert into any format.
for mm-dd-yyyy format see this link
[How to get current formatted date dd/mm/yyyy in Javascript and append it to an input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409299/how-to-get-current-formatted-date-dd-mm-yyyy-in-javascript-and-append-it-to-an-i)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [moment](http://momentjs.com/) and [angular moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) for date related stuff.

In the controller:

```
$scope.date = moment(<date>, 'YYYY/MM/DD');
```

In the view:

```
<p data-ng-bind="date | amDateFormat : 'MM/DD/YYYY'"></p>
```