# Bootstrap Form Today Date

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, forms, date

I want to display today's date into a bootstrap form while keeping the input type set to 'date', the same for another input that is input type is 'time'. I'm seeing solutions that involve the input type to be 'text'. Is there anyway to display today's date either via `Javascript` or `PHP`?

Comment: Are you looking to use a datepicker? since input type date only work on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/j2177yuw/1/. Use https://momentjs.com/ to get today date

```
document.getElementById('date').value = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Use datepicker instead since input type date only works on chrome.

Comment: Asnawi: don't copy paste the other answer. You have copied from this answer, which is very similar like your: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409299/how-to-get-current-formatted-date-dd-mm-yyyy-in-javascript-and-append-it-to-an-i

Comment: i copied from here only to get the current date. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-javascript. didn't know there are similar answer as your comment above

Comment: This line proved that it is copied: var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

Comment: U can see the link that i comment above. it's from different url. Nvm...i updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer!