# How to change datepicker date format to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, asp-classic

Currently, I have an `onchange` on a `datepicker` and it calls the following function

```
 $('#dtpFrDate').change(function() {

    var date2 = $('#dtpFrDate').datepicker('getDate'); 
    date2.setDate(date2.getDate() -1); 

    document.getElementById('dtpToDate').innerHTML = date2.toLocaleDateString();
});
```

But during `onchange` my date format is [image: d/MM/YYYY]

how to get DD/MM/YYYY? Please help.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409299/how-to-get-current-formatted-date-dd-mm-yyyy-in-javascript-and-append-it-to-an-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toLocaleDateString` take  default local language from your device.To desire format you can use `en-GB`

```js
$('#dtpFrDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
$('#dtpFrDate').change(function() {
  var date2 = $('#dtpFrDate').datepicker('getDate');
  date2.setDate(date2.getDate() - 1);
  document.getElementById('dtpToDate').innerHTML = date2.toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
  console.log(date2.toLocaleDateString()); //My device lang is en-US
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input id=dtpFrDate type='text'>
<div id='dtpToDate'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jQuery DatePicker, you can add the format you desire to your DatePicker

```
var date = $('#dtpFrDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }).val();
```