# Convert Facebook JSON created_time of String format to other format

Tags: jquery, html, json

I'm developing a website and I'm trying to get `created_time` from Facebook's JSON. I was successful in that and I got it as `2018-04-17T17:25:23+0000`.

Now this should be converted into other format like `2018/04/17  5:23pm`

My challenge now is to convert that into other format.

Please help me to convert the string formatted time from JSON object to another date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var date = new Date('2018-04-17T17:25:23+0000');
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var year = date.getFullYear();
var new_format = month  + '/' + day  + '/' + year; // format :m/d/y
```

[More information](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp)

Comment: thanks this is very useful... thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

With your example date above, you can simply create a javascript date object like `var date = new Date('2018-04-17T17:25:23+0000');` and use this for creating any specific date formats.

See [How to get current formatted date dd/mm/yyyy in Javascript and append it to an input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409299/how-to-get-current-formatted-date-dd-mm-yyyy-in-javascript-and-append-it-to-an-i) for creating a new format

Comment: thanks this is very useful... thank you very much :-)