# Sequelize raw query format datetime

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, datetime, sequelize.js

How to format the datetime in the raw query, my database is mysql. The format i want is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS`, but now it is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss:000Z`.

Comment: What languages do you use? PHP?

Comment: No, i use javascript, Node.js

Comment: [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49893279/convert-facebook-json-created-time-of-string-format-to-other-format/49893562#49893562)

Comment: Thank you, but this not work

Comment: show me your code  please

Comment: data = await sequelize.query(sql, {
                    type: QueryTypes.SELECT
                });

Comment: It's not clear. You need to parse your date first, then put it in to your query

Comment: My sql is 'SELECT updateTime from mytable', the 'updateTime' field type is DATETIME, in query result, the format is 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss:000Z', i want fromat is 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'

Comment: For example `2018-05-08T10:02:30.000Z` right?

Comment: Yes, but i need is like  '2018-05-08 10:02:30'

Comment: Ok I have no idea about Sequelize. Good luck

Answer (score -1):

In defaults option, Sequelize return UTC format.

If you want to change it to `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` add `dateStrings: true` in `dialectOptions`

**example :**

```
const options = {
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    port: process.env.MYSQL_PORT,
    dialectOptions: {
        dateStrings: true
    }
    logging: true
};
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.MYSQL_NAME, process.env.MYSQL_USER, process.env.MYSQL_PASS, options);
```