# How to convert date format(Fri Jun 22 2018 14:37:47 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)) to DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I am using `material-ui/DatePicker` I am getting date in full format I need only the **DD-MM-YYYY**

```
import DatePicker from 'material-ui/DatePicker';
```

datepicker Component

```
<DatePicker
   hintText=""
   formatDate={(date) => moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY')}
   value={this.state.contractDate}
   onChange={this.handleContractDateChange}
  />
```

On change Function looks like below

```
handleContractDateChange = (event, date) => {
    this.setState({
              contractDate: date,
            });

          }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current formatted date dd/mm/yyyy in Javascript and append it to an input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409299/how-to-get-current-formatted-date-dd-mm-yyyy-in-javascript-and-append-it-to-an-i)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/ojp0kkz619

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see in the documentation (https://v0.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker) the prop `formatDate` is just for formatting the value of the date picker that is displayed in the field after picking a date. Your `onChange` handler still gets called with the date object. You have to call `moment.format()` again in your onChange handler.

```js
handleContractDateChange = (event, date) => {
  const formattedDate = moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
  // Use formattedDate

  this.setState({
    contractDate: date,
  });
}
```

Comment: date is not populating in the UI,

Comment: It is formating but date is not populating in the UI

Comment: This is not correct answer at all. momentjs is **NOT** supporting `DD-MM-YYYY` format. If you will run it will show you warning in `console logs`

Answer (score 2):

There is a method to convert JS Date Object to DD-MM-YYYY which is as follows

```
function formatDate(oDate) {
    var oTempDate = new Date(oDate),
        sMonth = '' + (oTempDate.getMonth() + 1),
        sDay = '' + oTempDate.getDate(),
        iYear = oTempDate.getFullYear();

        if (sMonth.length < 2) { sMonth = '0' + sMonth; }
        if (sDay.length < 2) { sDay = '0' + sDay; }

        return [sDay, sMonth, iYear].join('-');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like below using pure JavaScript:

```js
let date = new Date("Fri Jun 22 2018 14:37:47 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)");

let dd = date.getDate();
let mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
let yyyy = date.getFullYear();

console.log(dd + "-" + mm + "-" + yyyy);
```